# Looking for LaTeX consultant

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

Is there anybody who would be interested in working with me as a LaTeX / Beamer consultant?  I can do my best to post minimum working examples and to incorporate the advice I'm given.  I will continue to do so, but I can't always do it; my skills are not that good.  And I'm ok with my bad LaTeX skills.  I would just really want to have someone look at my code and help me work through a few things.  Is there a way to communicate via email?

Comment: You could try the [counsultants at TUG](http://www.tug.org/consultants.html).

Comment: Thank you.  Is anybody else available outside of TUG?

Comment: Also see [Where to find people for hire with LaTeX skills and designer skills?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19553/where-to-find-people-for-hire-with-latex-skills-and-designer-skills)

Comment: Thank you Peter for your comment.  Is there a way for me to be in touch through this form with anybody who might be interested?  I don't see any links other than TUG or message board forums to post specific questions.  I would dearly like to work with someone via email.  Is there a way to get into an email exchange through this forum?

Comment: @JG The two links point to people who do commercial TeX work: I would imagine that contacting them directly will be possible from the information available, as they have livings to make! TeX.sx works best with questions that have some general relevance, hence for example the idea of a MEW from which people can understand a problem independent of the exact detail of one use case. It's therefore not set up for 'one-to-one' trouble shooting.

Comment: You should try posting to: http://latex-community.org/forum/

Comment: OP would benefit from interactions with Thorston.  He is an incredibly caring, intelligent, gentile, thoughtful, patient, and beautiful moderator.  Beautiful inside and out.  Such an amazing moderator.  Follows the rules so well.  Gives amazing feedback.

Comment: What is a Thorston?

Comment: @J G.  Thorsten is a moderator on latex-community.org/forum.  He is the kindest man alive.