# Have you ever been paid for typesetting / developing tex code?

Tags: typography

> Hopefully not "off topic"... Kinda similar to the [showcase](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/).

People with solid *TeX skills, have you ever been paid for typesetting - i.e. someone else's "copy" (content) - and/or developing tex code?
If so:

- What did you do?
- Who paid you?
- Did you learn anything?

Comment: One example of such an experience can be found in the answer on https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6591/job-advertising.

Comment: Not that anyone is interested in this question but there's [book design - Where can I find people for hire with LaTeX skills and designer skills? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19553/where-can-i-find-people-for-hire-with-latex-skills-and-designer-skills) on the site.