# Is there a site where I can enter a latex expression, and it shows me an image of the compiled expression?

Tags: compiling, tools, online

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Compiling documents online](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3/compiling-documents-online)

Hi,

So I'm preparing a powerpoint slideshow and would like to add in some math expressions without creating a new latex document, copying the images from a pdf, and etc...

Does anyone know of a website that lets you input a math expression from latex, and it displays an image of that expression, that I can just save and use?

That would be amazing..

Thanks

EDIT:
From the thread mentioned below, this is the tool fitting what I wanted the most:
http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php

Comment: You're probably looking for this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3/compiling-documents-online

Comment: Check out [Auto-LaTeX Equations for Google Docs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/auto-latex-equations/iaainhiejkciadlhlodaajgbffkebdog?utm_source=https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3955/), it does all the rendering work for you and looks great!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the online services mentioned in that other thread, there are a number of standalone equation editors which will compile a LaTeX expression into an image file, provided your computer already has LaTeX installed.

- I use LaTeXit! (Mac OSX), which
  is included in the MacTeX
  distribution. It's got plenty of features, including the ability to edit the default preamble (to include packages, custom commands, etc.)
- Laeqed seems to be a similar
  cross-platform tool, although I've
  never used it myself.
- Cutting out the middleman, there are also at least two LaTeX plugins for PowerPoint: TeXPPT and MyTexPoint. I can't vouch for these either, but they do exist!

Answer (score 0):

I like the instant view editor of [mathtran](http://www.mathtran.org/toys/jfine/editor2.html).

Answer (score 0):

The online editor http://www.sitmo.com/latex/ has a GUI and is designed only for math formulas. It generates the previews (almost) instantly.