# How to make beamer overlays with Tikz node

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, overlays

I have a diagram of 4 nodes in my beamer slide.

```
  \begin{figure}[h]
  \begin{centering}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[system/.style={draw,rectangle,rounded corners=3,minimum width=2cm,text width=1.8cm,text centered}]
    \node [system] (fe) {Feature Extraction};
    \node [system] (am) [right=of fe] {Acoustic Model};
    \node [system] (lm) [right=of am] {Language Model};
    \node [system] (d) [below=of lm] {Decoder};

    \draw[->] (fe) |- (am);
    \draw[->] (am) |- (d);
    \draw[->] (lm) -- (d.north);

  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{centering}
  \end{figure}
```

How can I in a second slide "highlight" one of the nodes, like I can do with `<alert@n>` for a item in a list?

With highlighting I mean for example giving a color and thickening the lines.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

I used to do this according to Andrew's solution until I read his note #2, and it reminded me that PGF's keys can do pretty much anything.  The key (excuse the pun) is to create a key that processes other keys conditional on the slide number:

```
\tikzset{onslide/.code args={<#1>#2}{%
  \only<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}} 
}}
```

Using `\pgfkeysalso` doesn't reset the current key path, whereas `\pgfkeys` or `\tikzset` would.  The `.code args` key handler means that

```
onslide=<overlay specification>{keys}
```

causes the the following code to be expanded:

```
\only<overlay specification>{\pgfkeysalso{keys}}
```

Then you can use the key `onslide=<overlay specification>{keys}` to set keys only on specific slides.  The slightly inelegant twist is that if your overlay specification contains commas the entire pair of overlay spec and keys has to be embraced.

Here is a complete example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzset{onslide/.code args={<#1>#2}{%
  \only<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
}}
\tikzset{temporal/.code args={<#1>#2#3#4}{%
  \temporal<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}}{\pgfkeysalso{#4}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
}}

\tikzstyle{highlight}=[red,ultra thick]


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
 \begin{figure}[h]
  \begin{centering}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    system/.style={draw,rectangle,rounded corners=3,minimum width=2cm,text width=1.8cm,text centered},
    node distance=2cm
  ]
    \node [system,onslide=<3->{highlight},anchor=center] (fe) {Feature Extraction};
    \node [system,onslide={<2,4>{green}}] (am) [right=of fe.center] {Acoustic Model};
    \node [system,temporal=<3>{blue}{highlight}{green}] (lm) [right=of am.center] {Language Model};
    \node [system] (d) [below=of lm.center] {Decoder};

    \draw[->] (fe) |- (am);
    \draw[->] (am) |- (d);
    \draw[->] (lm) -- (d.north);

  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{centering}
  \end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

You will be disappointed about the jiggling of your picture when the line thickness keys are applied.  You might have to avoid relative positioning to make that go away.

For more on key handlers like `.code args`, see the `pgfkeys` section of the TikZ-PGF manual.

Comment: Fantastic!  I'm going to use this in future.  I clearly need to delve into the depths of pgfkeys to learn the Deeper Magic.  To avoid the jiggling, but still use relative positioning, one could use the *centres* of the nodes for positioning rather than their edges.

Comment: @Andrew: Thanks for the idea, and good point about the positioning fix. True confessions: I have the PGF manual loaded in iBooks so I can (and have) read it on my iPad on the train.

Comment: Given my comment on this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3/compiling-documents-online, I don't think that I would get much sympathy calling you a "PGF-Nerd" on that one!  If I had an iPad, and used a mode of transport where it was safe to read such (*not* walking given our current weather), I'd probably do the same.

Comment: I tried to modify this solution to work with the beamer command `\temporal` but failed. Of course one can use 3 `onslide` options to achieve the behavoir of `\temporal`. But still, can you add an example that uses `\temporal` directly?  Thanks.

Comment: @TysonWilliams: See edits.

Comment: Couldn't make the jiggling go away even with positioning from the center.  I think maybe I'd have to manually set the bounding box.

Comment: Can some one please add some explanation to onside/.code arg and temporal/.code arg?

Comment: @NAASI: I added a sentence or two to what is there already.  `onside` and `temporal` are just the names of the keys.  `.code args` is a special *key handler* that creates a macro.

Comment: @ Mattiew...can you tell me how can I adjust fill option in this example. I don't know how to change system/.style to get fill of 50% of given color

Comment: @NAASI: that's a different question than the one on this page.  You can search or write a new question, though.

Comment: I agree that its a different question. Can you tell me how can I highlight boxes while keeping the text inside them in black

Comment: I've noticed that this only seems to work if you put the `\tikzset` before `\begin{document}`. That is, I tried to place it just before my `tikzpicture` and got some errors...

Comment: @Seamus This must have something to do with beamer's nonstandard expansion of frames.  I think putting it in the preamble is the right thing to do anyway.

Comment: Works perfectly in my case - thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 17):

There are a few ways to do this, exactly which is best will depend on what you want the highlighting effect to be.  One way is to have separate nodes with the two styles and then show one on one slide and one on the other.  Another way is to define a style that is wrapped in an `\only`.  Actually, using beamer's reimplementation of `\newcommand`, one can make `\tikzset` overlay-aware.  Here's a couple of possibilities:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newcommand<>{\btikzset}[2]{\alt#3{\tikzset{#1}}{\tikzset{#2}}}

\tikzset{highlight/.style={red,fill=green,text=blue}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}[h]
  \begin{centering}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[system/.style={draw,rectangle,rounded corners=3,minimum width=2cm,text width=1.8cm,text centered}]
    \node [system] (fe) {Feature Extraction};
    \node<1> [system] (am) [right=of fe] {Acoustic Model};
    \node<2> [system,highlight] (am) [right=of fe] {Acoustic Model};
    \node [system] (lm) [right=of am] {Language Model};
    \node [system] (d) [below=of lm] {Decoder};

    \draw[->] (fe) |- (am);
    \draw[->] (am) |- (d);
    \draw[->] (lm) -- (d.north);

  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{centering}
  \end{figure}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}[h]
  \begin{centering}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[system/.style={draw,rectangle,rounded corners=3,minimum width=2cm,text width=1.8cm,text centered}]
  \btikzset<2>{highlighton2/.style={highlight}}{highlighton2/.style={}}

    \node [system] (fe) {Feature Extraction};
    \node [system,highlighton2] (am) [right=of fe] {Acoustic Model};
    \node [system] (lm) [right=of am] {Language Model};
    \node [system] (d) [below=of lm] {Decoder};

    \draw[->] (fe) |- (am);
    \draw[->] (am) |- (d);
    \draw[->] (lm) -- (d.north);

  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{centering}
  \end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Notes:

1. I found that `\renewcommand<>` didn't work, possibly because I was making `\tikzset` take two arguments - thus having it work like `\alt` rather than `\only`.  This was to avoid complaints of unknown keys.  An alternative would be to define an empty style, say `highlightOn` at the start and then have `\tikzset` map `highlightOn` to `highlight` on frame 2 and do nothing on other frames.  This would work with `\renewcommand<>`:

   ```
   \renewcommand<>{\tikzset}[1]{\only#2{\beameroriginal{\tikzset}{#1}}}


   \tikzset{highlight/.style={red,fill=green,text=blue}}
   \tikzset{highlighton2/.style={}}
   ```

   Then in the frame:

   ```
   \tikzset<2>{highlighton2/.style={highlight}}
   ```
2. Perhaps the truly elegant way would be to define a new key, "highlight on=", using the code handler.  But I've only just learnt of the existence of that so I'll leave that solution to someone else.