# Converting beamer slides to animated images

Tags: beamer, conversion, animations, gif

As a follow up to [Highlighting specific parts of a TikZ drawing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23548/highlighting-specific-parts-of-a-tikz-drawing), I'd like to know how to generate an animated image (`gif`) from a series of `beamer` slides.

Martin Scharrer came up with this example:

[image: Drawing 1]

Some hints on cropping the PDF file are also welcome. `=)`

Comment: I don't know the solution but my belief is the solution is possible using beamer or within LaTeX.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I generated that animated GIF the following way under Ubuntu Linux. It should work under other OSs as well because the external software is also available for Windows, Mac and others.

This assumes a `beamer` `frame` with several overlays as a starting point. The code for the GIF above can be found in my answer to [Highlighting specific parts of a TikZ drawing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23548/highlighting-specific-parts-of-a-tikz-drawing/23550#23550).

1. Ensure otherwise empty slides, e.g. `\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}%`
2. Ensure that all slides have the same size.
3. Compile to PDF (directly or indirectly).
4. Crop the PDF, e.g. using `pdfcrop <file>.pdf`.
5. Use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) to generate an animated GIF from the multi-page PDF:

   ```
   convert -verbose -delay 50 -loop 0 -density 300 <file>-crop.pdf <file>.gif
   ```

   Change the settings to your liking.
   `-verbose` is not really required.
   `-delay` states the duration of every image in the animation in 1/100 s.
   `-loop` states the number of repeats. `0` here means repeat indefinitely.
   `-density` determines the density for the raster image in dots-per-inch (dpi). This will influence the GIF size and is required because the PDF is a vector graphic. You can also use `300x300` etc. to select the X and Y density separately.

Here also an external example showing a diagram I had in one of my scientific publications: [MP-DPWM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBgZm.gif) (300k)

I might add support for this to `standalone`. Conversion support is already added in the developer version.

Comment: @MartinScharrer, follow your steps, I can't get animated GIF. I only get the first slide of the pdf file in my GIF file. How to solve it? Thanks. My system is Windows 7. I use Ghostscript 9.06.

Comment: @PigCry: The above uses ImageMagick not Ghostscript and works fine with me. No idea why you are only get the first page.

Comment: @PigCry: I have the same issue on the mac.  See my [question at Apple-SX](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/86177/imagemagick-convert-multipage-pdf-to-animated-gif).  You can workaround with `pdftk`.

Comment: That's a great trick which I've been using a lot. However, in rare cases it did not work, but then using [this chain](http://phyletica.org/imagemagick/) saved the day for me.

Comment: If you have problem with this, look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42928765/convertnot-authorized-aaaa-error-constitute-c-readimage-453 (I hope to save a bit of time to fellows LaTeXers...)

Answer (score 19):

For those who need non Beamer version, see the following.

### LaTeX Input File:

In this illustration I use PSTricks.

```
% travelingwave.tex
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pstricks-add,multido}
\newcommand\Left{0}
\newcommand\Bottom{-0.9}
\newcommand\Right{3.14}
\newcommand\Top{0.9}

\parindent=0pt
\paperwidth=\dimexpr\Right cm\relax
\paperheight=\dimexpr\Top cm - \Bottom cm\relax
\special{papersize=\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight}
\topmargin=-72.27pt
\oddsidemargin=-72.27pt
\pagecolor{black}

\begin{document}
\multido{\r=0+7.5}{48}
{
    \begin{pspicture*}(\Left,\Bottom)(\Right,\Top)
    \psplot[plotpoints=300,algebraic,linecolor=yellow]{\Left}{\Right}{0.9*sin(2*(x-\r*Pi/360))}
    \end{pspicture*}\newpage
}
\end{document}
```

### Batch File:

```
rem compile.bat takes a LaTeX input file without extension.
echo off
latex %1
dvips -t unknown %1
gswin32c -dAutoRotatePages=/None -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=%1.pdf %1.ps
convert -verbose -delay 25 -loop 0 -density 300 %1.pdf %1.gif
rem acrord32 %1.pdf
del %1.log
del %1.aux
del %1.dvi
del %1.ps
```

For the sake of simplicity, save both `travelingwave.tex` and `compile.bat` in the same directory. To compile, type `compile travelingwave` in DOS-command, and hit enter. Done!

### Result:

[image]

### Notes:

1. See [ImageMagick v6 Examples -- Animation Basics](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_basics/) for the detailed description about `convert`'s switches.
2. If `\pagecolor{<any-color-including-white>}` is disabled, we will get an effect as follows. 
   [image]
3. ImageMagick's `convert` invokes GhostScript `gswin32c.exe` behind the scene as follows.
   [image]

Comment: I guess, the `\pagecolor{<any-color-including-white>}` makes the background no longer transparent.

Answer (score 11):

I do not know if my answer meets the requirements of how the answers should be posted on this site (since it has practically no `LaTeX` code involved),  but here it comes.

---

With the emergence of online tools it has become easy to convert documents of a certain extent into others, without the need to download any programs. All those tools are easy-to-use and so not need any space in our computer.

Since the `beamer` output is a `PDF` file, we can convert `PDF` to `GIF` with [EZGIF](https://ezgif.com/pdf-to-gif) by following these simple steps:

1. `Upload` the PDF document
2. `Set up` the GIF (choose slides and delay amount)
3. `Convert!`

Here is an example:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

After spending a few hours on ImageMagick with no result (I kept getting error messages), I decided to go for a Photoshop + Acrobat Pro solution. Here's how I did it.

---

Required software

- Acrobat Pro (I'm using Acrobat X), or any other PDF reader that allows you to export or save the PDF pages as images
- Photoshop (I'm using CS3, and presumably newer, or even slightly older, versions will work as well)

---

### Steps:

1. Generate a PDF file of your Beamer slides
2. In Acrobat Pro, go to `File` > `Save as` > `Image` > `<select PNG or JPEG>`. In the pop-up window, select `Settings...` on the right, and under "Coversion" change "Resolution" to `600 pixels/inch` or above (the default resolution is very low). Then click `OK` and `Save`, and images of each page will be saved to the specified location as `<PDF_Name>_Page_#.png`.
3. Open Photoshop, go to `File` > `Script` > `Load Files into Stack`. `Browse` and select all the image files generated in step 2 and click `OK`. Now all the pages should be imported as layers of a Photoshop document.
4. Go to `Window` and select `Animation` to show the animate panel.
5. From the flyout menu in the top right of the animation panel, select `Make frames from layers`, and then `Reverse frames` to set the frames in correct order.
6. Select all the frames in the animation panel (click the first frame, and then `Shift`+click the last one), and choose a frame rate at the bottom right corner of any frame. You can also set the repeat option at the bottom left of the panel. Preview by clicking the play button.
7. Lastly, go to `File` > `Save for Web & Devices...` > `Save` (top right) > give it a name, and make sure to select `.gif` as the extension. Then we're done!

Note: If you want to crop the PDF file, then after step 6, select all layers in the layers panel, use the Crop Tool to crop the images.

[image: gif of string recognition]

[image: gif of wave]

Comment: This is not a `latex` solution! However, I appreciate your effort.

Comment: @pushpen.paul: Well, the other solutions are not `LaTeX` solutions either; they use ImageMagick `;)`

Comment: @KevinC Yeah! But your method is very much manual! :-)