# Math Error: The function 'f' already exists

Tags: pgfplots, errors

I'm trying the answer of @Jake from [Automate derivative representation in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55571/automate-derivative-representation-in-tikz), which is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{point legend/.style={},
    point 1/.style={anchor=south},
    point 2/.style={anchor=south}
}
\newcommand{\derivative}[5]{
\begin{scope}[declare function={f(\x)=#1;}]
    \addplot [thick, red, latex-latex] {f(x)} node [anchor=west] {#2};
    \addplot [black, mark=*] coordinates {(#3,{f(#3)}) (#4,{f(#4)})}
        node [pos=0,/pgfplots/point 1] {$P_1$}
        node [pos=1,/pgfplots/point 2] {$P_2$};
    \pgfplotsextra{
        \pgfmathsetmacro\first{f(#3)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\second{(f(#4)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\xdiff{#4-#3}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\ydiff{f(#4)-f(#3)}
        \draw (axis cs:#3,\first) -| (axis cs:#4,\second);
        \draw [|-|,yshift=-2ex] (axis cs:#3,\first) -- node [inner sep=1pt,fill=white] {\pgfmathprintnumber{\xdiff}} (axis cs:#4,\first);
        \draw [|-|,xshift=2ex] (axis cs:#4,\first) -- node [inner sep=1pt, fill=white] {\pgfmathprintnumber{\ydiff}} (axis cs:#4,\second);
        \matrix at (rel axis cs:1,1) [matrix of nodes,/pgfplots/point legend] {#5\\};
    }
    \end{scope}
}

\pgfplotsset{
    azetinaplot/.style={
        width=7cm,
        height=7cm,
        axis lines=middle,
        xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel=$y$,
        enlarge y limits,
        clip=false
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        azetinaplot,
        domain=-20:370, samples=100,
        xmin=-20, xmax=370,
        point 1/.append style={anchor=south east},
        point 2/.append style={anchor=east}]
    \derivative{sin(\x)}
        {$f(x)=\sin(x)$}
        {290}{340}
        {$P_1=(290\,,\,-0.94)$\\$P_2=(340\,,\,-0.34)$}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But I have error `Math Error: The function 'f' already exists`. Does anyone know why the error occurs, I tried both in TexStudio and Overleaf

Comment: Workaround: remove the `declare function` from the `scope` and put it as an argument to the `tikzpicture` (i.e.: `\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x)=sin(\x);}]`)

Comment: @Marijn Thank you very much! It works! Do you know why it doesn't work for me, although it should?

Comment: Probably the current version of `pgfplots` uses `scope` and `declare function` in a different way compared to the 2012 version from the other question. I'm not sure what the problem is exactly, I would expect it to work, but in this way to issue is avoided.

Comment: You could also just move it outside the scope, i.e. `\newcommand{\derivative}[5]{
\tikzset{declare function={f(\x)=#1;}}
\begin{scope} ....`. That way you can use the macro the same way as in Jake's answer. I also do not think it has to do with the pgfplots version since the error arises also for older versions of pgfplots, so maybe a Ti*k*Z update is responsible instead.

Comment: The one potential drawback with both suggested workarounds is that you can use the `\derivative` macro only once per `tikzpicture`. Use it twice, and you'll get the same error, albeit for a more obvious reason (you actually do declare `f` twice).

Comment: @TorbjørnT. oh ok, do you know how it can be solved?

Comment: I was actually a bit inaccurate, you can't use it more than once per `axis` environment, but if you have two `axis` in the same `tikzpicture`, then you can have a `\derivative` in each. One workaround for that, if you actually need it, is to make the function name an (optional) argument to the `\derivative` macro. I can post an answer with that, if you want to.

Comment: I should say though that the macro should in that case be rewritten more, as the legend is placed at a fixed location, and you can't have two legends in the same place, so using it more than once in the same `axis` doesn't work that well.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. So it is not possible to plot multiple curves in one graph? Is there workaround for it?

Comment: I never said it wasn't possible. It is possible, but the `\derivative` macro needs some modifications.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Ah ok! Do you have suggestion how to modify it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an alternative definition of `\derivative`. It differs from Jake's original in a few respects, and is used like this:

```
\derivative[<optional function name, default f>]
           {<mandatory function definition>}
           {<mandatory function label>}
           {<mandatory x_1>}{<mandatory x_2>}
           [<optional position of legend, default rel axis cs:1,1>]
```

The first optional argument can be used to avoid the "function already exists"-error. If not specified, e.g. `\derivative{sin(\x)}...`, then `f` is used. The second time you invoke `\derivative` in an `axis`, specify some other name, e.g. `\derivative[g]{cos(\x)}...`.

The last optional argument is used to define the position of the legend. If you don't specify it, the legend is placed in the top right corner of the `axis`.

I removed the last argument of the original macro, where the legend entries were written, instead making those part of the macro definition.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse} % for \NewDocumentCommand
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\pgfplotsset{point legend/.style={},
    point 1/.style={anchor=south},
    point 2/.style={anchor=south}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\derivative}{O{f} m m m m O{rel axis cs:1,1}}{
\tikzset{declare function={#1(\x)=#2;}}
    \addplot [thick, red, latex-latex] {#1(x)} node [anchor=west] {#3};
    \addplot [black, mark=*] coordinates {(#4,{#1(#4)}) (#5,{#1(#5)})}
        node [pos=0,/pgfplots/point 1] {$P_1$}
        node [pos=1,/pgfplots/point 2] {$P_2$};
    \pgfplotsextra{
        \pgfmathsetmacro\first{#1(#4)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\second{#1(#5)} % removed first (
        \pgfmathsetmacro\xdiff{#5-#4}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\ydiff{#1(#5)-#1(#4)}
        \draw (axis cs:#4,\first) -| (axis cs:#5,\second);
        \draw [|-|,yshift=-2ex] (axis cs:#4,\first) -- node [inner sep=1pt,fill=white] {\pgfmathprintnumber{\xdiff}} (axis cs:#5,\first);
        \draw [|-|,xshift=2ex] (axis cs:#5,\first) -- node [inner sep=1pt, fill=white] {\pgfmathprintnumber{\ydiff}} (axis cs:#5,\second);
        \matrix at (#6) [matrix of math nodes,/pgfplots/point legend] {
         P_1=(#4\,,\,\pgfmathparse{#1(#4)}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult})\\
         P_2=(#5\,,\,\pgfmathparse{#1(#5)}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult})\\};
    }
}

\begin{document}



\pgfplotsset{
    azetinaplot/.style={
        width=10cm,
        height=8cm,
        axis lines=middle,
        xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel=$y$,
        enlarge y limits,
        clip=false
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        azetinaplot,
        domain=-20:370, samples=100,
        xmin=-20, xmax=370,
        point 1/.append style={anchor=south east},
        point 2/.append style={anchor=east}]
    \derivative{sin(\x)}
        {$f(x)=\sin(x)$}
        {290}{340}
        [axis cs:150,-1] % position for the legend


    % above we used the default function name f
    % here we use the first optional argument to give the function the name g instead
    \derivative[g]{cos(\x)+2}
        {$f(x)=\cos(x)$}
        {200}{300}
        [axis cs:170,2.5] % position for the legend

    \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note this doesn't actually answer your question the way you phrased it. I have no idea why the original version doesn't work now.

Comment: Is in `\pgfmathsetmacro\second{(#1(#5)}` there the bracket missing?

Comment: @FacebFaceb No, it's the first `(` that is unnecessary. (That's the way you had it in your original code by the way, I didn't notice it before.) Edit: fixed code in answer.

Comment: haha I also noticed it after I posted my question. But when I put the `\begin{tikzpicture}` inside `\begin{figure}[H] \centering \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.46\textwidth} \centering`, then it's not centered anymore

Comment: @FacebFaceb That is a completely separate and different issue, so normally I'd suggest you ask a new question. If I were to guess, I'd guess that the diagram is wider than the `0.46\textwidth` of the `subfigure`, which makes it poke out the right side of the `subfigure`. Make the plot narrower. (Note I increased the `width` in the `azetinaplot` style from 7cm to 10cm, because it looked better for the specific plot I made for the example. If you copied that setting as well, that could be the cause.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Would you mind also posting your answer on the original question? Then that could be marked as the accepted answer, which would prevent others stumbling on the same problem