# How can I add third point in plot?

Tags: pgfplots, coordinates

This question is about the answer of @TorbjørnT. in [Math Error: The function 'f' already exists](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/439023/math-error-the-function-f-already-exists).

How can I add the third point, which has x coordinate as the mean of first two points and y coordinate is this x coordinated evaluated.

See picture

[image]

I tried (I indicated which lines I added)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse} % for \NewDocumentCommand
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\pgfplotsset{point legend/.style={},
    point 1/.style={anchor=south},
    point 2/.style={anchor=south}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\derivative}{O{f} m m m m O{rel axis cs:1,1}}{
\tikzset{declare function={#1(\x)=#2;}}
    \addplot [thick, red, latex-latex] {#1(x)} node [anchor=west] {#3};
    \addplot [black, mark=*] coordinates {(#4,{#1(#4)}) (#5,{#1(#5)}) ((#5+#4)/2,#1((#5+#4)/2))} % I edited this line
        node [pos=0,/pgfplots/point 1] {$P_1$}
        node [pos=1,/pgfplots/point 2] {$P_2$}
        node [pos=0,/pgfplots/point 3] {$P_3$}; % I edited this line
    \pgfplotsextra{
        \pgfmathsetmacro\first{#1(#4)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\second{#1(#5)} % removed first (
        \pgfmathsetmacro\xdiff{#5-#4}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\ydiff{#1(#5)-#1(#4)}
        \draw (axis cs:#4,\first) -| (axis cs:#5,\second);
        \draw [|-|,yshift=-2ex] (axis cs:#4,\first) -- node [inner sep=1pt,fill=white] {\pgfmathprintnumber{\xdiff}} (axis cs:#5,\first);
        \draw [|-|,xshift=2ex] (axis cs:#5,\first) -- node [inner sep=1pt, fill=white] {\pgfmathprintnumber{\ydiff}} (axis cs:#5,\second);
        \matrix at (#6) [matrix of math nodes,/pgfplots/point legend] {
         P_1=(#4\,,\,\pgfmathparse{#1(#4)}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult})\\
         P_2=(#5\,,\,\pgfmathparse{#1(#5)}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult})\\};
    }
}

\begin{document}



\pgfplotsset{
    azetinaplot/.style={
        width=10cm,
        height=8cm,
        axis lines=middle,
        xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel=$y$,
        enlarge y limits,
        clip=false
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        azetinaplot,
        domain=-20:370, samples=100,
        xmin=-20, xmax=370,
        point 1/.append style={anchor=south east},
        point 2/.append style={anchor=east}]
    \derivative{sin(\x)}
        {$f(x)=\sin(x)$}
        {290}{340}
        [axis cs:150,-1] % position for the legend


    % above we used the default function name f
    % here we use the first optional argument to give the function the name g instead
    \derivative[g]{cos(\x)+2}
        {$f(x)=\cos(x)$}
        {200}{300}
        [axis cs:170,2.5] % position for the legend

    \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I seems to work when you replace `/2` by `*0.5` -- for whatever reason.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{matrix}
    \pgfplotsset{
        point legend/.style={},
        point 1/.style={anchor=south},
        point 2/.style={anchor=south},
        point 3/.style={anchor=south},                  % <-- added
        azetinaplot/.style={
            width=10cm,
            height=8cm,
            axis lines=middle,
            xlabel=$x$,
            ylabel=$y$,
            enlarge y limits,
            clip=false,
        },
    }
    \NewDocumentCommand{\derivative}{O{f} m m m m O{rel axis cs:1,1}}{
        \tikzset{declare function={#1(\x)=#2;}}
        %
        \addplot [thick, red, latex-latex] {#1(x)}
            node [anchor=west] {#3}
        ;
        \addplot [black, mark=*] coordinates {
            (#4,{#1(#4)})
            (#5,{#1(#5)})
        }
            node [pos=0,/pgfplots/point 1] {$P_1$}
            node [pos=1,/pgfplots/point 2] {$P_2$}
        ;
        % we need another `\addplot' for the third point to avoid drawing a line
        % also to point 2
        \addplot [black, mark=*, forget plot] coordinates {
            ({0.5*(#5+#4)},{#1(0.5*(#5+#4))})           % <-- repaced `/2' by `*0.5'
        }
            node [pos=0.5,/pgfplots/point 3] {$P_3$}    % <-- added
        ;
        \pgfplotsextra{
            \pgfmathsetmacro\first{#1(#4)}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\second{#1(#5)}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\xdiff{#5-#4}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\ydiff{#1(#5)-#1(#4)}
            %
            \draw (axis cs:#4,\first) -| (axis cs:#5,\second);
            \draw [|-|,yshift=-2ex] (axis cs:#4,\first)
                -- node [inner sep=1pt,fill=white] {\pgfmathprintnumber{\xdiff}}
                    (axis cs:#5,\first);
            \draw [|-|,xshift=+2ex] (axis cs:#5,\first)
                -- node [inner sep=1pt,fill=white] {\pgfmathprintnumber{\ydiff}}
                    (axis cs:#5,\second);
            %
            \matrix at (#6) [matrix of math nodes,/pgfplots/point legend] {
                P_1=(#4\,,\,\pgfmathparse{#1(#4)}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult})\\
                P_2=(#5\,,\,\pgfmathparse{#1(#5)}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult})\\
            };
        }
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        azetinaplot,
        domain=-20:370, samples=100,
        xmin=-20, xmax=370,
        point 1/.append style={anchor=south east},
        point 2/.append style={anchor=east},
    ]
        \derivative{sin(\x)}
            {$f(x)=\sin(x)$}
            {290}{340}
            [axis cs:150,-1] % position for the legend

        % above we used the default function name f
        % here we use the first optional argument to give the function the name g instead
        \derivative[g]{cos(\x)+2}
            {$f(x)=\cos(x)$}
            {200}{300}
            [axis cs:170,2.5] % position for the legend

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: thanks! Do you know how to remove the line between P3 and P2?

Comment: With the current implementation this is not possible, because the point is added in the `\addplot coordinates` list. Thus, either *no* or *all* lines can be removed. Before we start iterating other requirements for your solution, please state **all of them** in your question.

Comment: that's all of the requirements. I would like the 3 points P1, P2, P3 but only P1 and P2 should be connected

Comment: @FacebFaceb, please edit your question and add there all your requirements. in comments they are not well visible to others. and clarify, which line should be removed. so far i see only function curve, which is going through  P3 and P2. do you like interrupt it?

Comment: @FacebFaceb, did my answer answer your question? If yes, it would be nice if you could [upvote](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) it (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and/or marking it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).

Answer (score 1):

One way to go is to draw the line not as plot but as line. That way you can draw any fraction of it. For instance, here I draw only 50% of it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse} % for \NewDocumentCommand
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\pgfplotsset{point legend/.style={},
    point 1/.style={anchor=south},
    point 2/.style={anchor=south}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\derivative}{O{f} m m m m O{rel axis cs:1,1}}{
\tikzset{declare function={#1(\x)=#2;}}
    \addplot [thick, red, latex-latex] {#1(x)} node [anchor=west] {#3};
    \pgfplotsextra{
        \pgfmathsetmacro\first{#1(#4)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\second{#1(#5)} % removed first (
        \pgfmathsetmacro\xdiff{#5-#4}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\ydiff{#1(#5)-#1(#4)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\xmid{(#4+#5)/2}
        \path (axis cs:#4,{#1(#4)}) -- (axis cs:#5,{#1(#5)})
        node[pos=0,label=above:$P_1$]{\pgfuseplotmark{*}}
        coordinate[pos=0.5] (mid)
        node[pos=1,label=left:$P_2$]{{\pgfuseplotmark{*}}};
        \draw (axis cs:#4,{#1(#4)}) -- (mid);
        \node[label=above:{$P_3$}]at (axis cs:\xmid,{#1(\xmid)}) {\pgfuseplotmark{*}};
        \draw (axis cs:#4,\first) -| (axis cs:#5,\second);
        \draw [|-|,yshift=-2ex] (axis cs:#4,\first) -- node [inner sep=1pt,fill=white] {\pgfmathprintnumber{\xdiff}} (axis cs:#5,\first);
        \draw [|-|,xshift=2ex] (axis cs:#5,\first) -- node [inner sep=1pt, fill=white] {\pgfmathprintnumber{\ydiff}} (axis cs:#5,\second);
        \matrix at (#6) [matrix of math nodes,/pgfplots/point legend] {
         P_1=(#4\,,\,\pgfmathparse{#1(#4)}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult})\\
         P_2=(#5\,,\,\pgfmathparse{#1(#5)}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult})\\};
    }
}
 % node[pos=0.5,label=above left:$P_3$]{\pgfuseplotmark{*}}
\begin{document}



\pgfplotsset{
    azetinaplot/.style={
        width=10cm,
        height=8cm,
        axis lines=middle,
        xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel=$y$,
        enlarge y limits,
        clip=false
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        azetinaplot,
        domain=-20:370, samples=100,
        xmin=-20, xmax=370,
        point 1/.append style={anchor=south east},
        point 2/.append style={anchor=east}]
    \derivative{sin(\x)}
        {$f(x)=\sin(x)$}
        {290}{340}
        [axis cs:150,-1] % position for the legend


    % above we used the default function name f
    % here we use the first optional argument to give the function the name g instead
    \derivative[g]{cos(\x)+2}
        {$f(x)=\cos(x)$}
        {200}{300}
        [axis cs:170,2.5] % position for the legend

    \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]