# bold letter or word spacing for text animation

Tags: beamer, spacing

I want to make a text animation movie for my wife for Valentines.  My first thought was to use the beamer package and have a different word in bold on each slide.  I would then convert the pdf to jpegs and use each slide as a frame.  As I am reading the slides in the audio, the words will go to bold in sequence.  The problem is that the bold letters are wider than the non-bold letters, so the words slide around a little between frames depending on which word is bold.  I would like this to go away, but I don't know the best way to fix it.

My first thought was to try and set the letter spacing for non-bold text to match that of bold text.  I don't know exactly how to do that, but I suspect it won't look that great.  Trying to set the word spacing to what it would be if all the text were bold seems like it might look better, but I am not sure it is feasible.

How do I do this well?

Comment: What if you changed the color of the text rather than changing the font size? I believe that this is the way it is done for displaying lyrics of karaoke songs, which is a different context, but has some similarities.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a first step:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\widthofbold}[1]{%
  \settowidth{\dimen0}{\textbf{#1}}%
  \makebox[\dimen0]{#1}}
\newcommand<>{\myword}[1]{%
  \alt#2{\textbf{#1}}{\widthofbold{#1}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \Large
  \myword<1>{This}
  \myword<2>{is}
  \myword<3>{how}
  \myword<4>{much}
  \myword<5>{I}
  \myword<6>{love}
  \myword<7>{you}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The idea is to set the word using `\alt<slide>{<stuffA>}{<stuffB>}` where `<stuffA>` is set in `\textbf` on slide `<slide>` and `<stuffB>` is set in a box of width `\textbf{<stuffA>}` on any other slide.

Comment: Thanks Werner.  You say this is a first step, but I think it does everything I need.  This will get me the still images I need.  From  there it is all movie making stuff not related to latex (I think).

Comment: I am accepting your answer as doing everything I need to do in latex.  From here I think it is just python to help me make copies of the images to determine how long each slide will hold at a certain fps rate and then I will use apple movie tools to do the rest.  Thanks again.

Comment: @ryanGT: I used `convert` to create the animated GIF. See [Converting `beamer` slides to animated images](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23727/5764). You can adjust the frame rate using `-delay <num>`.

Comment: We also love you. ♥ `:)`