# Creating interactive slide (beamer)

Tags: beamer

I want to create an interactive slide, which will have two parts:

1. In the left side, some comments will be given in `enumerate` environment (one will be highlighted at each overlay)
2. In the right side, an image will accompany the currently highlighted text (say, an arrow will be shown in that image)

For example, have a look at frame numbered 23 of this [file](http://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/grc/slides/gcc-improvements.pdf).

**Screen-shot:**
[image]

What is the best way to do this?

As per asked, this is (a short version of) what I am trying...

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}
\begin{enumerate}
\item this is 1
\item this is 2
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.75\textwidth}
\only<1> {\includegraphics[width=.75\textwidth]{fig4-2}}
\only<2> {\includegraphics[width=.75\textwidth]{fig4-3}}
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The images are:

fig4-2

[image]

fig4-3

[image]

## Update

---

As @GonzaloMedina replies on the left-hand-side part (that solves my current problem), now I am left with dynamically creating the images. That means, rather than creating each image separately and then including is a tiresome and monotonous job. There should be some better way to reproduce one image from its predecessor. To complete the whole question, as per his (Gonzalo Medina) suggestion, I am creating this follow-up [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195618/creating-interactive-slide-beamer-2).

Comment: Please provide a Minimum Working Example rather than expecting people to start creating things from scratch!

Comment: @cfr My attempt is very basic. Just create separate images and use `\pause` for including each image. I think it will be to *naive* for the expert latex-ians.

Comment: So? It still saves people having to start with `\documentclass...`. Note that it matters what the images are, for example. Code shows people what you are trying to do in a way which your question does not at the moment. (If the image is created on-the-fly, that's different than if it is included as an external file.) Moreover, you can set up an MWE using example images which saves people having to do that part of the work.

Comment: @cfr OK, I am adding it. But I cannot post the actual images, so give me some time to make some edits.

Comment: Excellent. Note that the `mwe` package provides sample images for this purpose which you can just use `\includegraphics{example-image-a}` or whatever. That way, you don't need to post images.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

[image]

The code:

```
    \documentclass{beamer}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

    \newcounter{tmp}
    \newcommand<>\Highlight[1]{%
    \stepcounter{tmp}%
    \only#2{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \fill[green!60!black,opacity=0.5] 
      ([xshift=-.2em,yshift=2ex]pic cs:start-\thetmp)
        rectangle  
      ([xshift=.2em,yshift=-1ex]pic cs:end-\thetmp);
    \end{tikzpicture}}%
    \tikzmark{start-\thetmp}#1\tikzmark{end-\thetmp}%
    }

    \begin{document}

    \begin{frame}

    \begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item \Highlight<+>{this is 1}
    \item \Highlight<+>{this is 2}
    \item \Highlight<+>{this is 3}
    \item \Highlight<+>{this is 4}
    \item \Highlight<+>{this is 5}
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.75\textwidth}
    \only<1> {\includegraphics[width=.75\textwidth]{fig4-2}}
    \only<2> {\includegraphics[width=.75\textwidth]{fig4-3}}
    \only<3> {\includegraphics[width=.75\textwidth,height=0.7cm]{example-image-a}}
    \only<4> {\includegraphics[width=.75\textwidth,height=0.7cm]{example-image-b}}
    \only<5> {\includegraphics[width=.75\textwidth,height=0.7cm]{example-image-c}}
    \end{minipage}
    \end{frame}

    \end{document}
```

Using the `tikzmark` library, the `\Highlight` command places a colorized rectangle in the background. I assumed here that the text to be highlighted spans no more than a line; otherwise, a modification on the definition will be required; for example,

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\newcounter{tmp}
\newcommand<>\Highlight[1]{%
\stepcounter{tmp}%
\only#2{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\fill[green!60!black,opacity=0.5] 
  ([xshift=-.2em,yshift=2ex]pic cs:start-\thetmp)
    rectangle  
  ([xshift=.2em,yshift=-1ex]pic cs:end-\thetmp);
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\tikzmark{start-\thetmp}#1\hfill\tikzmark{end-\thetmp}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \Highlight<+>{this is 1 and some other text}
\item \Highlight<+>{this is 2}
\item \Highlight<+>{this is 3}
\item \Highlight<+>{this is 4}
\item \Highlight<+>{this is 5}
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth}
\only<1> {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig4-2}}
\only<2> {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig4-3}}
\only<3> {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=0.7cm]{example-image-a}}
\only<4> {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=0.7cm]{example-image-b}}
\only<5> {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=0.7cm]{example-image-c}}
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The code needs two or thee runs to stabilize.

Comment: Just an off-topic question: How did you create the animation?

Comment: @pushpen.paul Using `ImageMagick`; the procedure is described in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23728/3954.

Comment: Thanks. For the present situation, my problem is solved (as I have already created the images in separate files). Now, for future reference, I need help for creating images on the fly (`tikzpicture` embedded in one `tex` file). Should I update this question or create a follow up question?

Comment: @pushpen.paul A follow-up one seems the best choice since the new issue is apparently independent from the issue discussed here.