# ! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=5000000]. for foreach

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, pgfmathparse

I was blocked on this point, I'm going to compile a code in which I'm using the command **foreach**:

```
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\iar}{{\RodLength*\iBngle/180}}%L=\iBngle*x=\RodLength*\iBngle/360%360 ou 180 angles finale % le pas
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\tar}{{(\RodLength*\iBngle/360)-\iar}}
\foreach \jar in {\iar, \tar, ...,\tar}{
....
}
```

when i compile this code i get the following error:

```
 Runaway argument? {\pgfkeysvalueof {/pgf/inner ! TeX capacity
 exceeded, sorry [main memory size=5000000]. <argument> ...pgf@xc
 {\pgfkeysvalueof {/pgf/inner 
                                                   xsep}}\advance \pgf@x by 2... l.98 }
        !  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
 Transcript written on fig_serie_2.log.
```

her is my [code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/419575/):

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}% 
\def\relRad{0.3}
\def\RodLength{1.65}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{110}
\begin{animateinline}[loop, poster = first, controls=false]{24}
%\foreach \iBngle in {0,2,...,100}{
\multiframe{100}{iBngle=0+2}{
\pgfmathsetmacro{\iAngle}{140}%35
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{110}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5,tdplot_main_coords]
\useasboundingbox[tdplot_screen_coords] (-2.05,-1.2) rectangle 
(2.5,1.5);
\coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
\node[red, left] at (O) {$O$};
\draw[thick,->] (O) -- (2,0,0) node[anchor=north]{$x_0$};
\draw[thick,->] (O) -- (0,1.5,0) node[anchor=west]{$y_0$};
\draw[thick,->] (O) -- (0,0,1.5) node[anchor=south]{$z_0$};
\draw[thick,->] (O) -- (0.3,0,0) node[anchor=north, left]{$\vec i_0$};
\draw[thick,->] (O) -- (0,0.3,0) node[near end, below]{$\vec j_0$};
\draw[thick,->] (O) -- (0,0,0.3) node[anchor=south, right]{$\vec 
k_0$};
\draw[thick, opacity=0.3] (-2,-1.5,0) -- (2,-1.5,0) -- (2,1.5,0) --(-2,1.5,0) -- cycle;
\fill[red,opacity=0.2](-2,-1.5,0) -- (2,-1.5,0) -- (2,1.5,0) --(-2,1.5,0) -- cycle;
\tdplotdrawarc[thick, color=red]{(2,-1.5,0)}{-0.3}{-90}{0}{anchor=180}
{$\pi/2$}% <-
\tdplotdrawarc[thick, color=red, ->]{(O)}{0.5}{0}{\iAngle+\iBngle}
{anchor=180, below}{$\omega\cdot t$}%
\tdplotdrawarc[thick,dotted, color=violet, ->]{(O)}{0.55}{90}
{90+\iAngle+\iBngle}{anchor=180,above}{$\omega\cdot t$}
\tdplotdrawarc[thick, color=purple, dashed]{(O)}
{\RodLength*\iBngle/180}{0}{360}{anchor=180}{} %%changed
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{\iAngle+\iBngle}{00}{0}%%changed
\begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords]
\draw[thick, dashed, opacity=1, ->] (0,0,0) -- (2.5,0,0)node[above]
{$x_1$};
\draw[thick, dashed, opacity=1, ->] (0,0,0) -- (0,2.5,0)node[above] 
{$y_1$};
\draw[thick,->] (O) -- (0.3,0,0) node[anchor=north, above left]{$\vec 
i_1$};
\draw[thick,->] (O) -- (0,0.3,0) node[near end, above]{$\vec j_1$};
\end{scope}
\ifthenelse{\iBngle<180}{
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{{\iAngle+\iBngle}}{00}{0} %<- changed that in order to rotate the rod
\begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords]
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\iar}{{\RodLength*\iBngle/180}}%L=\iBngle*x=\RodLength*\iBngle/360%360 ou 180 angles finale % le pas
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\tar}{{(\RodLength*\iBngle/360)-\iar}}
\foreach \jar in {\iar, \tar, ...,\tar}{
\draw[ultra thick, color=orange, opacity=1] (0,0,0) -- 
(\RodLength,0,0)node[near end, below left] {$(T)$};
\coordinate[label=below right:$C$] (A1) at 
({\RodLength*\iBngle/180},0,0.3); 
\fill[blue,thick] (A1) circle (0.3pt);
\coordinate[label=above:$I_1$] (I1) at 
({\RodLength*\iBngle/180},0,0);%changed
\fill[blue,thick] (I1) circle (0.3pt);}
\end{scope}
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{{\iAngle+130}}{90}{0} %<-
\begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords]
\draw[pattern=north west lines, pattern color=blue, opacity=0.5 ] (A1) 
 circle (\relRad);
\node[] at (45:0.4cm){$D$};
\draw[-latex,blue] (A1) -- ++(0,0,0.7)node[below]{$k_1$};  %<-
\draw[-latex,blue] (A1) -- ++(0,0,0.7)node[below]{$i_1$};  %<-
\draw[-latex,blue] (A1) -- ++({-0.7*cos(\iBngle/\relRad+\iAngle)},0,{0.7*sin(\iBngle/\relRad+\iAngle)})node[right]{$i_2$}; %<-
\draw[-latex,blue] (A1) -- ++({-0.7*sin(\iBngle/\relRad)},0,{-0.7*cos(\iBngle/\relRad)})node[below]{$k_2$};  %<-
\end{scope}}{
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{{\iAngle+\iBngle}}{00}{0} %<- changed that in order to rotate the rod
\begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords]
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\iar}{{\RodLength*\iBngle/180}}%L=\iBngle*x=\RodLength*\iBngle/360%360 ou 180 angles finale % le pas
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\tar}{{(\RodLength*\iBngle/360)-\iar}}
\foreach \jar in {\iar, \tar, ...,\tar}{
\draw[ultra thick, color=orange, opacity=1] (0,0,0) -- 
(\RodLength,0,0)node[near end, below left] {$(T)$};
\coordinate[label=below right:$C$] (A1) at 
({\RodLength*\iBngle/180},0,0.3); 
\fill[blue,thick] (A1) circle (0.3pt);
\coordinate[label=above:$I_1$] (I1) at 
({\RodLength*\iBngle/180},0,0);%changed
\fill[blue,thick] (I1) circle (0.3pt);}
\end{scope}
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{{\iAngle+130}}{90}{0} %<-
\begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords]
\draw[pattern=north west lines, pattern color=blue, opacity=0.5 ] (A1) 
 circle (\relRad);
\node[] at (45:0.4cm){$D$};
\draw[-latex,blue] (A1) -- ++(0,0,0.7)node[below]{$k_1$};  %<-
\draw[-latex,blue] (A1) -- ++(0,0,0.7)node[below]{$i_1$};  %<-
\draw[-latex,blue] (A1) -- ++({-0.7*cos(\iBngle/\relRad+\iAngle)},0,{0.7*sin(\iBngle/\relRad+\iAngle)})node[right]{$i_2$}; %<-
\draw[-latex,blue] (A1) -- ++({-0.7*sin(\iBngle/\relRad)},0,{-0.7*cos(\iBngle/\relRad)})node[below]{$k_2$};  %<-
\end{scope}}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```

Comment: please edit your example so people can run it and reproduce the error to debug, it is very hard to debug fragments that use undefined commands.

Comment: I can't compile your code either but I guess the problem is `\foreach \jar in {\iar, \tar, ...,\tar}{`. Try replacing it by `\foreach \jar in {\iar, \tar}{` or something else that makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *real* problem is, as you stated, in the `\foreach \jar in {\iar, \tar, ...,\tar}` line. The values of `\iar` and `\tar` when TeX arrives here are both zero, so the command reads `\foreach \jar in {0, 0, ...,0}`, which results in an infinite loop `:)`

The value of the loop increment (`\tar`) cannot be zero, otherwise this will occur. The value of both `\iar` and `\tar` are zero because `\iBngle` is zero.

So the *first* fix is to change the line

```
\multiframe{100}{iBngle=0+2}{
```

to something else, other than zero. Since the increment here is two, I suggest an odd value, so that it'll never be zero, no matter how many iterations.

The second issue, is these lines:

```
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\iar}{{\RodLength*\iBngle/180}}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\tar}{{(\RodLength*\iBngle/360)-\iar}}
```

The `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` does exactly as it says. You have `\RodLength = 1.65` and, after the first fix, `\iBngle = 1`. This gives `1.65*1/180 = 0.009` that, after truncation is zero. And again both `\iar` and `\tar` are zero.

Replace these lines by:

```
\pgfmathparse{\RodLength*\iBngle/180}
\let\iar\pgfmathresult
\pgfmathparse{(\RodLength*\iBngle/360)-\iar}
\let\tar\pgfmathresult
```

and you'll have the proper value, without truncation.

I fixed your code and it runs fine, but unfortunately my PDF viewer doesn't play the animation, so I couldn't check if it works.

On a side note, this line: `\foreach \jar in {\iar, \tar, ...,\tar}`. Is it supposed to be like this? As far as I understand loops, this will iterate only once for `\jar=\iar`, and if this is correct, then there's no point in using the `\foreach` at all.

Here's the full code:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}% 
\def\relRad{0.3}
\def\RodLength{1.65}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{110}
\begin{animateinline}[loop, poster = first, controls=false]{24}
%\foreach \iBngle in {0,2,...,100}{
\multiframe{100}{iBngle=1+2}{
\pgfmathsetmacro{\iAngle}{140}%35
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{110}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5,tdplot_main_coords]
\useasboundingbox[tdplot_screen_coords] (-2.05,-1.2) rectangle 
(2.5,1.5);
\coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
\node[red, left] at (O) {$O$};
\draw[thick,->] (O) -- (2,0,0) node[anchor=north]{$x_0$};
\draw[thick,->] (O) -- (0,1.5,0) node[anchor=west]{$y_0$};
\draw[thick,->] (O) -- (0,0,1.5) node[anchor=south]{$z_0$};
\draw[thick,->] (O) -- (0.3,0,0) node[anchor=north, left]{$\vec i_0$};
\draw[thick,->] (O) -- (0,0.3,0) node[near end, below]{$\vec j_0$};
\draw[thick,->] (O) -- (0,0,0.3) node[anchor=south, right]{$\vec 
k_0$};
\draw[thick, opacity=0.3] (-2,-1.5,0) -- (2,-1.5,0) -- (2,1.5,0) --(-2,1.5,0) -- cycle;
\fill[red,opacity=0.2](-2,-1.5,0) -- (2,-1.5,0) -- (2,1.5,0) --(-2,1.5,0) -- cycle;
\tdplotdrawarc[thick, color=red]{(2,-1.5,0)}{-0.3}{-90}{0}{anchor=180}
{$\pi/2$}% <-
\tdplotdrawarc[thick, color=red, ->]{(O)}{0.5}{0}{\iAngle+\iBngle}
{anchor=180, below}{$\omega\cdot t$}%
\tdplotdrawarc[thick,dotted, color=violet, ->]{(O)}{0.55}{90}
{90+\iAngle+\iBngle}{anchor=180,above}{$\omega\cdot t$}
\tdplotdrawarc[thick, color=purple, dashed]{(O)}
{\RodLength*\iBngle/180}{0}{360}{anchor=180}{} %%changed
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{\iAngle+\iBngle}{00}{0}%%changed
\begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords]
\draw[thick, dashed, opacity=1, ->] (0,0,0) -- (2.5,0,0)node[above]
{$x_1$};
\draw[thick, dashed, opacity=1, ->] (0,0,0) -- (0,2.5,0)node[above] 
{$y_1$};
\draw[thick,->] (O) -- (0.3,0,0) node[anchor=north, above left]{$\vec 
i_1$};
\draw[thick,->] (O) -- (0,0.3,0) node[near end, above]{$\vec j_1$};
\end{scope}
\ifthenelse{\iBngle<180}{
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{{\iAngle+\iBngle}}{00}{0} %<- changed that in order to rotate the rod
\begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords]
\pgfmathparse{\RodLength*\iBngle/180}%L=\iBngle*x=\RodLength*\iBngle/360%360 ou 180 angles finale % le pas
\let\iar\pgfmathresult
\pgfmathparse{(\RodLength*\iBngle/360)-\iar}
\let\tar\pgfmathresult
\foreach \jar in {\iar, \tar, ...,\tar}{
\draw[ultra thick, color=orange, opacity=1] (0,0,0) -- 
(\RodLength,0,0)node[near end, below left] {$(T)$};
\coordinate[label=below right:$C$] (A1) at 
({\RodLength*\iBngle/180},0,0.3); 
\fill[blue,thick] (A1) circle (0.3pt);
\coordinate[label=above:$I_1$] (I1) at 
({\RodLength*\iBngle/180},0,0);%changed
\fill[blue,thick] (I1) circle (0.3pt);}
\end{scope}
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{{\iAngle+130}}{90}{0} %<-
\begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords]
\draw[pattern=north west lines, pattern color=blue, opacity=0.5 ] (A1) 
 circle (\relRad);
\node[] at (45:0.4cm){$D$};
\draw[-latex,blue] (A1) -- ++(0,0,0.7)node[below]{$k_1$};  %<-
\draw[-latex,blue] (A1) -- ++(0,0,0.7)node[below]{$i_1$};  %<-
\draw[-latex,blue] (A1) -- ++({-0.7*cos(\iBngle/\relRad+\iAngle)},0,{0.7*sin(\iBngle/\relRad+\iAngle)})node[right]{$i_2$}; %<-
\draw[-latex,blue] (A1) -- ++({-0.7*sin(\iBngle/\relRad)},0,{-0.7*cos(\iBngle/\relRad)})node[below]{$k_2$};  %<-
\end{scope}}{
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{{\iAngle+\iBngle}}{00}{0} %<- changed that in order to rotate the rod
\begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords]
\pgfmathparse{\RodLength*\iBngle/180}%L=\iBngle*x=\RodLength*\iBngle/360%360 ou 180 angles finale % le pas
\let\iar\pgfmathresult
\pgfmathparse{(\RodLength*\iBngle/360)-\iar}
\let\tar\pgfmathresult
\foreach \jar in {\iar, \tar, ...,\tar}{
\draw[ultra thick, color=orange, opacity=1] (0,0,0) -- 
(\RodLength,0,0)node[near end, below left] {$(T)$};
\coordinate[label=below right:$C$] (A1) at 
({\RodLength*\iBngle/180},0,0.3); 
\fill[blue,thick] (A1) circle (0.3pt);
\coordinate[label=above:$I_1$] (I1) at 
({\RodLength*\iBngle/180},0,0);%changed
\fill[blue,thick] (I1) circle (0.3pt);}
\end{scope}
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{{\iAngle+130}}{90}{0} %<-
\begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords]
\draw[pattern=north west lines, pattern color=blue, opacity=0.5 ] (A1) 
 circle (\relRad);
\node[] at (45:0.4cm){$D$};
\draw[-latex,blue] (A1) -- ++(0,0,0.7)node[below]{$k_1$};  %<-
\draw[-latex,blue] (A1) -- ++(0,0,0.7)node[below]{$i_1$};  %<-
\draw[-latex,blue] (A1) -- ++({-0.7*cos(\iBngle/\relRad+\iAngle)},0,{0.7*sin(\iBngle/\relRad+\iAngle)})node[right]{$i_2$}; %<-
\draw[-latex,blue] (A1) -- ++({-0.7*sin(\iBngle/\relRad)},0,{-0.7*cos(\iBngle/\relRad)})node[below]{$k_2$};  %<-
\end{scope}}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you @Phelype Oleinik, can you label for me a link to a document,  in order to understand  the difference between **\pgfmathtruncatemacro** and **\pgfmathparse**

Comment: @moradov There's not much secret to it. `\pgftruncatemacro` will perform the calculation and truncate the result and store the result in the given macro. `\pgfmathparse` will also perform the calculation, but without truncation, and the result will be stored in `\pgfmathresult` (that's why after `\pgfmathparse` I used `\let\iar\pgfmathresult`). You can find more detailed information about this macros in chapter `54 -- Floating Point Unit Library` of the [PGF manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf?lang=en).

Comment: @moradov You're welcome :)