# Smartdiagram Package: Distance between sequence diagram elements

Tags: smartdiagram

as I write in the topic I like to have a little distance between the elements in a sequence diagram.

A minimal example:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A smartdiagram}
\smartdiagramset{
    uniform color list=gray!60!white for 5 items,
    sequence item border color=black,
    sequence item text color=black,
    sequence item border size=1.2\pgflinewidth,
}
\scalebox{0.8}{
    \smartdiagramanimated[sequence diagram]{
        {Lastprofil $\left\{T_U\right\}$},
        {Wärmeströme $\left\{\dot{Q}\right\}$},
        {Temperatur-feld $\left\{T\right\}$},
        {Verformungs-feld $\left\{u\right\}$},
        {Fehler Wirk-\newline stelle $\left\{u_{TCP}\right\}$}
    }
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Is there a option I couldn't find?

Could you please help me?

Comment: Sorry, i edit my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could not come up with a clever way to fit your specific diagram on a slide but this is not what the question is about. In order to add a bit space between the items it is sufficient to say

```
\tikzset{sequence item/.append style={outer xsep=0.5ex}}
```

You probably want to do this locally unless you want all sequence diagrams to have this feature.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A smartdiagram}
\smartdiagramset{
    uniform color list=gray!60!white for 5 items,
    sequence item border color=black,
    sequence item text color=black,
    sequence item border size=1.2\pgflinewidth,
    sequence item height=4em
}
\begingroup\tikzset{sequence item/.append style={outer xsep=0.5ex}}
\smartdiagramanimated[sequence diagram]{
    {Lastprofil $\left\{T_U\right\}$},
    {W\"armestr\"ome $\left\{\dot{Q}\right\}$},
    {Temperatur-feld $\left\{T\right\}$}%,
%     {Verformungs-feld $\left\{u\right\}$},
%     {Fehler Wirk-\newline stelle $\left\{u_{TCP}\right\}$}
}\endgroup    

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For the future it would be great if you could post complete yet minimal examples.

Comment: Thank you very much. That is exactly what I wanted. I edit my post so that there is a minimal working example.

Comment: I have a question for further question: How did you make the animated graphic?

Comment: @pritzky There are some posts on this like [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23728/194703). One can use `convert`, I used `convert -density 300 -delay 144 -loop 0 -alpha remove <file.pdf> <ani.gif>`.