# Beamer overlays: changing font between slides

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, formatting, bold

I am creating slides with overlays in Beamer, using TiKZ to create a figure consisting mainly of text nodes.  The idea is that different parts of the figure are highlighted on each slide.  Initially it all appears in a light gray (I'm using "seagull" colours with a white background), and on each slide a different part of the figure is shown in full colour.

I've achieved this by basically drawing the figure twice: once in light gray, and then drawing it again using a sequence of "onslide" commands.  However, what I'd like is for text in a node to appear as bold face when it appears in colour.  Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\title{A test} 
\author{Me} 
\date{\today}

\begin{document} 

\begin{frame}   
  \maketitle 
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{This is the test slide}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,color=lightgray]
    \draw (current page.south west)++(1,1) coordinate (SW);
    \draw (SW)++(2,1) node {First bit of text};
    \draw (SW)++(4,3.5) node {Second bit of text};
    \draw (SW)++(6,6) node {Third and final text};
    \onslide<2>{\draw[color=blue] (SW)++(2,1) node {First bit of text};}
    \onslide<3>{\draw[color=blue] (SW)++(4,3.5) node {Second bit of text};}
    \onslide<4>{\draw[color=blue] (SW)++(6,6) node {Third and final  text};}     
  \end{tikzpicture}    
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Now there may well be an easier and more natural way of doing this; on the other hand it means I can position text wherever I want.

If I include a `text = \bfseries` in the second part of the above, then it seems to stick, and the lightgray text is also bold, which I don't want.  So - any ideas on how text will appear in a color and bold, and then go back to lightgray and normal when it's not highlighted?

Comment: To clearify: You want to highlight each text separately, first it is lightgray, than blue and bold and afterwards appears in lightgray again? Well, if you just overprint with `\textbf{}` the lightgray will still be there underneath the blue text, with a smaller width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want to achieve?

Draw the `lightgray` parts only on a specified number of slides using the `\only<frame_number>` command and afterwards use `\onlide<2>` (or another frame number` to draw the text in other font/color etc.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\title{A test} 
\author{Me} 
\date{\today}

\begin{document} 

\begin{frame}   
  \maketitle 
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{This is the test slide}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,color=red]
    \draw (current page.south west)++(1,1) coordinate (SW);
    \only<1,3-4>{\draw (SW)++(2,1) node {First bit of text};}
    \only<1-2,4>{\draw (SW)++(4,3.5) node {Second bit of text};}
    \only<1-3>  {\draw (SW)++(6,6) node {Third and final text}};
    \only<2>{\draw[color=blue] (SW)++(2,1) node {\textbf{First bit of text}};}
    \only<3>{\draw[color=blue] (SW)++(4,3.5) node {\textbf{Second bit of text}};}
    \only<4>{\draw[color=blue] (SW)++(6,6) node {\textbf{Third and final  text}};}     
  \end{tikzpicture}    
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I changed from `lightgray` to `red` just for the snapshot, because `lightgray` is hard to recognize in a screenshot.

[image]

Comment: That's perfect: clearly `only` is the answer to my query.  Thanks very much!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of drawing the content twice (which involves difficult to maintain code duplication), I suggest to just change the `color` and `font` attributes on the specific slides. In the following the `onslide=<overlay spec>{key=value, key=value}` TikZ style provides just that:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

% TikZ stile to apply keys only on specific beamer overlays
% onslide=<overlay spec>{key=value, key=value, ...}
\tikzset{onslide/.code args={<#1>#2}{%
  \only<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}%
}}



\title{A test} 
\author{Me} 
\date{\today}

\begin{document} 

\begin{frame}   
  \maketitle 
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{This is the test slide}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,color=red]
    \draw (current page.south west)++(1,1) coordinate (SW);
    \draw[onslide=<2>{color=blue, font=\bfseries}] (SW)++(2,1) node {First bit of text};
    \draw[onslide=<3>{color=blue, font=\bfseries}] (SW)++(4,3.5) node {Second bit of text};
    \draw[onslide=<4>{color=blue, font=\bfseries}] (SW)++(6,6) node {Third and final text};
  \end{tikzpicture}    
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The code may further be improved by defining an own style for the highlighting, so that you can easily change that later or reuse it on other frames:

```
\tikzset{highlight/.style={color=blue, font=\bfseries}} 

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,color=red]
  \draw (current page.south west)++(1,1) coordinate (SW);
  \draw[onslide=<2>{highlight}] (SW)++(2,1) node {First bit of text};
  \draw[onslide=<3>{highlight}] (SW)++(4,3.5) node {Second bit of text};
  \draw[onslide=<4>{highlight}] (SW)++(6,6) node {Third and final text};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

**Further References:**

- [Highlighting specific parts of a TikZ drawing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23548/highlighting-specific-parts-of-a-tikz-drawing)
- [Mindmap tikzpicture in beamer (reveal step by step)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55806/mindmap-tikzpicture-in-beamer-reveal-step-by-step)
- [Package aobs-tikz – TikZ styles for creating overlaid pictures in beamer](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/aobs-tikz)

Answer (score 1):

Better don't change font when highlighting, unless it is just a letter or single symbol. The widths and spacings change, which will led to labels wiggling around. To distracting. Better use color change only, say a (dark) gray vs red.