# What tikz commands support overlays (for beamer)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, overlays

I have been reading the source code for the template:
https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/beamer-arrows/wmqkckggvjsd
which clearly shows that path supports overlays, so you can have edges on certain slides only.

However I needed the same with `\draw` and doing something like `\draw<2->` doesn't work (compile error). Do overlays not work with draw? Where do I find an exhaustive list of overlays friendly tikz commands?

Comment: Are you by chance looking for the [aobs package](https://ctan.org/pkg/aobs-tikz)?

Comment: some related question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146908/beamer-overlay-specifications-for-a-tikzpicture https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185870/beamer-overlays-changing-font-between-slides https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6135/how-to-make-beamer-overlays-with-tikz-node

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question. But there is a special library for doing Ti*k*Z overlays in beamer: aobs. In addition, you can always work with `\only`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,overlay-beamer-styles}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{An example}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[background fill=red!50,%
fill on=<2>,%
rounded corners,%
] (koala) {koala bear};
\node[right=3cm of koala,
background fill=blue!50,%
fill on=<3>,%
rounded corners,%
] (marmot) {marmot};
\only<2>{
\draw[-latex] (koala) -- (marmot) node[midway,above]{envy};
}
\only<3>{
\draw[latex-] (koala) -- (marmot) node[midway,above]{like};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Till Tantau being the creator of `BEAMER` and `Tikz-PGF` the `overlay` work with `tikz`. Just add the overlay specification after the command name.

For example, here to make the transparency visible on the second and all subsequent images:
`draw<2->(0,0)--(2,0);`

If you had a compilation error it is not from the `overlay` placed on the `\draw` command. I place overlays on almost all my slideshows with `tikz` and I haven't had a compilation error yet.

Give a minimal example so that this error can be reproduced and corrected.