# No text=none in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

In TikZ, there are `draw=none` and `fill=none` options to turn off stroking and filling operations.  However, there doesn't appear to be a corresponding `text=none` option.  If I try `\tikz \node[text=none] {X};`, I get the error message "Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `none'."  (The `text=red` option does work as expected.)

- Is there indeed no `text=none` option?
- What are alternatives?  Is it reasonable to use `text opacity=0`, or is there something better?

I'm asking because I would like to create an "empty" node of the same size as a given image or text.  By referencing the anchors of this "empty" node, I can then animate the image or text moving in to occupy the same space.  The following is an example of what I'm trying to accomplish.  It uses `text opacity=0` based on @percusse's suggestion.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{animateinline}[autoplay,loop]{10}
  \multiframe{11}{iframe=0+1}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw}]
      \node[text opacity=0] (source) {Text};
      \node[text opacity=0] (target) at (2,2) {Text};

      \node at ($(source)!\iframe/10!(target)$) {Text};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\end{animateinline}

\end{document}
```

- Given this ultimate goal, is it preferable to use something like `\node {\phantom{Text}};`?

Comment: Are you basically just trying to set the size of the node, and you're using some text string to achieve this? In that case it's best to just use options like `minimum width`, and `inner sep`, as percusse said, instead of fiddling around with strings of text that have the right size.

Comment: @Jake I've edited my post with an example.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks! In that case, I think the `text opacity` key is the most practical.

Comment: The only difference I can see is the text selection in the resulting `.pdf`. Opacity leaves the text selectable but `\phantom` doesn't.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you don't need the text then it shouldn't be there anyway. Either you enlarge the node with `minimum width,height,inner sep` etc. or you can use the `text opacity` key comfortably.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[text opacity=0,draw=red,fill=yellow!25] (a) {Text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you also need some placeholder for a text, you can go slightly esoteric and get the width depth height info beforehand e.g. just for the width;

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathparse{width{"Text"}}
\edef\mywidth{\pgfmathresult}
\node[minimum width=\mywidth pt,draw=red,fill=yellow!25] (a) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: @percusse Should `text opacity=0` be preferred over using `\phantom`?

Comment: @HenryDeYoung Opacity solution does not get complicated if you make the node text `\large` etc. but you have to somehow send those font adjustments into the `\phantom` command say when the node is scaled etc. it may be a little more tedious in terms of code flexibility but I can't think of any obvious big reason for preference.

Comment: @Jake I was wondering about the image inclusion detail but indeed I don't see any reason why not to use.

Comment: `text opacity=0` might not be the best option when you want to print it. I once had the following issue: the text of my nodes was not visible in the pdf, but small parts of them appeared in the printed version. I "solved" the issue by setting the text color to the background color.

Comment: With `text opacity=0`, the text *is* always included in PDF: you can copy it. So, `\phantom` seems best in terms of confidentiality.

Comment: @PolGab: You're right, the text is indeed left in the PDF. Hm, don't know why it didn't work when I tried it last time.

Comment: @PolGab You are right. I tried to let OP know about it in my comment above too.

Comment: @percusse I don't think I understand your above point about complications of `\phantom` when the node text is made `\large`, when the node is scaled, etc.  Could you elaborate a little bit or point me to an existing discussion?

Comment: @HenryDeYoung It's not that important actually. Suppose you want to make all node fonts `\Large` or something like that using `\tikzset{}` constructs, I don't know if all the settings go into the `\phantom{}` argument automatically. It might not be the case for some settings such that you have to manually state `\phantom{\somesetting Text}`. Better safe than sorry :).

Comment: If you are using beamer overlays forcing one to put the changes in two places (text node and tikz node drawing options) makes it much more complicated. Much nicer to just use a nice \node [temporal=<3>{.. }{..}{..} ] command (once defined) than repeat this multiple places.

Comment: I am very sorry for the accidental down vote. I clicked by accident and then my internet connection went down, and now it won't let me change the vote :(

Answer (score 14):

you can use `\phantom{Text}`

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw=red,fill=yellow!25] (a) {\phantom{Text}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw=red,fill=yellow!25] (a) {{Text}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just to note - unfortunately, `\phantom` doesn't work for multiline text: e.g. `\node[draw=red,fill=yellow!25,align=center] (a) {\phantom{Text\\Test}};` will fail with `! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.`

Answer (score 9):

If one wants a true “phantom” text node (i.e. no selectable text in the resulting PDF) and doesn’t want to manually provide the `\phantom` macro, one can use one of the following solutions:

1. Using the undocumented keys `execute at begin node` and `execute at end node` one can use the `lrbox` environment (or manually with `\setbox`) a box which is then used inside `\phantom`:

   ```
   execute at begin node = \begin{lrbox}{\pgfutil@tempboxa},
   execute at end node   = \end{lrbox}\phantom{\usebox\pgfutil@tempboxa}
   ```

   This works very well for one-liner nodes and also (I assume) for multiparted nodes. Problems arise when the `text width` key is used because the needed `minipage` environment is setup outside of the stuff that is given to `execute at begin/end node`. (Obviously, we could just mimic this ourselves with a `minipage` and things from TikZ’ original setup).
2. After TikZ puts the text between `{` and `}` in a box it checks the values of the keys `text width`,  `text depth` and `text height` and corrects the box measures accordingly. After transformation, the node is created via the `\pgfnode` macro. We can intercept this here with the following setup (and a little help from `etoolbox`):

   ```
   \usepackage{etoolbox}
   \patchcmd\tikz@fig@continue{\tikz@node@transformations}{%
     \iftikz@node@phantom
       \setbox\pgfnodeparttextbox\hbox{%
         \vrule height\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox depth\dp\pgfnodeparttextbox width0pt%
         \vrule height0ptdepth0ptwidth\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox}%
     \fi\tikz@node@transformations}{}{}
   ```

   This would simply overwrite the `\pgfnodeparttextbox` with rules that are exactly the width, height and depth of the original `\pgfnodeparttextbox` (just as `\phantom` would do).

   Personally, I prefer this solution, combined with the following keys/conditional, that also provides (besides the `text=none` syntax) a key `phantom`.

   ```
   \newif\iftikz@node@phantom
   \tikzset{
     phantom/.is if=tikz@node@phantom,
     text/.code=%
       \edef\tikz@temp{#1}%
       \ifx\tikz@temp\tikz@nonetext
         \tikz@node@phantomtrue
       \else
         \tikz@node@phantomfalse
         \let\tikz@textcolor\tikz@temp
       \fi}
   ```
3. Another option can be used with the upcoming version of TikZ which provides a `node contents` key. We can create a key that takes its argument and passes it to `node contents` encompassed in a `\phantom`. This will only work for one-liners.

   ```
   Phantom/.style={node contents=\phantom{#1}}
   ```

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\makeatletter
\newif\iftikz@node@phantom
\tikzset{
  phantom/.is if=tikz@node@phantom,
  text/.code=%
    \edef\tikz@temp{#1}%
    \ifx\tikz@temp\tikz@nonetext
      \tikz@node@phantomtrue
    \else
      \tikz@node@phantomfalse
      \let\tikz@textcolor\tikz@temp
    \fi,
  Phantom/.style={node contents=\phantom{#1}},% only CVS, only single line
  PHantom/.style={
    execute at begin node=\setbox\pgfutil@tempboxa\hbox\bgroup,
    execute at end node=\egroup\phantom{\usebox\pgfutil@tempboxa}}
}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd\tikz@fig@continue{\tikz@node@transformations}{%
  \iftikz@node@phantom
    \setbox\pgfnodeparttextbox\hbox{%
      \vrule height\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox depth\dp\pgfnodeparttextbox width0pt%
      \vrule height0ptdepth0ptwidth\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox}%
  \fi\tikz@node@transformations}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tikz[nodes={draw, text width=2cm}]\path
  node[green]        {Text text text text text text text}
  node[PHantom, red] {Text text text text text text text};
\foreach \iframe[evaluate={\iframe=\iframe/10}] in {0,...,10}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes=draw]
  \node[text=none] (source)                  {Text};
  \node[phantom]   (target) at (2,2)         {Text};
  \node[gray]               at (1,1) [Phantom=Text];

  \path (source.center) -- node[pos=\iframe] {Text} (target.center);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

And why not : `text = yellow!25` ?

and like Andrew wrote in his comment : `\node[yellow!25,fill,draw=red] (a) {Text};` in this  case, you set the colors for text, draw and fill.

`draw` and `fill` are different options. If you don't use these options, by default the shape is not draw and not filled but with `text` (it's equivalent to `draw=false`), the text is always displayed and by default the color used is black.

If you write `\node[name=s] (a) {Text};` the name of the node is `a`, if it was possible to write `\node[text=none] (a) {Text};` the text will be `Text`. `text` is a color; if you want you can define :  `\definecolor{none}{rgb}{1,1,1}` and it's possible to define `none` to be the fill color.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[text=yellow!25,draw=red,fill=yellow!25] (a) {Text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Or `\node[yellow!25,fill,draw=red] (a) {Text};` as a colour by itself sets all three colours to it (text,fill, and draw).  This makes it easier to modify later as there's only one colour to change.

Comment: yes Andrew you are right. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue when using this wonderful [hint](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6135/how-to-make-beamer-overlays-with-tikz-node) for easily combining beamer overlays and options passed to tikz commands and looking to avoid duplicating overlay specifications.  For this purpose setting text opacity to 0 is fine.  Using the command described in the hint we can compare doing this with text opacity.

```
\node [temporal=<2>{Bres}{text opacity=0}{resdone}] {\( \phi^A_{i,s}(x) \) };
```

As opposed to what is required to also do it the `right way' and just change the node text.

```
\node [temporal=<3-6>{Bres}{text opacity=0}{resdone}] { \only<1-2,7->{\( \phi^A_{i,s}(x) \)} };
```