# hf-tikz markin has to be on the 1st slide to be referable by overlay anotation

Tags: beamer, overlays, hf-tikz

I am making a presentation in beamer. I would like to show some equations with description using overlays.

code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[beamer,markings]{hf-tikz}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Total Electron Content} 
        \uncover<1->{
        \begin{equation*}
            n_{ion} = 1- \frac{40.3 N_e}{f^2}
        \end{equation*}
        }

        \uncover<2->{
        \begin{equation*}               
            \Delta \rho_{ion}=\frac{40.3}{f^2}\tikzmarkin<{1,3}>[mark at=0.93]{col}(0.2,-0.5)(-0,0.7)\int_S N_e\mathrm{d}S\tikzmarkend{col}         
        \end{equation*}
        }
\uncover<3->{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\coordinate (col-aa) at ($(col)+(-2,-1.8)$);
\node[align=right,left] at (col-aa) {\small{TEC}};
\path[-stealth,red,draw] (col-aa) -| ($(col)+(1,-1.55)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This works OK since the first slide does not show the highlighted equation. The `\tikzmarkin<{1,3}>` can be there and would not affect anything.
[image: beamer example]

However in case I would like to put the equation on the slide 1 and than highlight it on the 2nd, it does not work. It needs the `\tikzmarkin{col}` specified from the beginning, but, I do not want to show it there.

part of the code:

```
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Total Electron Content} 
        \begin{equation*}               
            \Delta \rho_{ion}=\frac{40.3}{f^2}\tikzmarkin<2>[mark at=0.93]{col}(0.2,-0.5)(-0,0.7)\int_S N_e\mathrm{d}S\tikzmarkend{col}         
        \end{equation*}

\uncover<2>{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\coordinate (col-aa) at ($(col)+(-2,-1.8)$);
\node[align=right,left] at (col-aa) {\small{TEC}};
\path[-stealth,red,draw] (col-aa) -| ($(col)+(1,-1.55)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{frame}
```

error:

```
! Package pgf Error: No shape named col is known.

See the pgf package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.20 \end{frame}

?
```

Is it possible to make it work somehow?

Comment: The problem is that with `\uncover` the content is also processed on the slides where it is not shown, the `\tikzmarkin<2>` on the other hand only defines `col` on the specified slides, apparently. Either you use `\only<2>` on the `tikzpicture` (as it is `overlay`ed, there wouldn’t be any difference anyway) or you change the `hf-tikz` styles (somehow) to [`invisible`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6155/16595) on slide `1`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel The substitution of `\uncover<2>` with `\only<2>` did all what I needed...the problem was the '_process all_' behaviour of `\uncover` I was not considering. Please, make your comment as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qrrbrbirlbel in the comment already explained the issue: my answer tries also to show a simpler way to make annotations.

In the OP's code, the `markings` option is used only in theory: the mark is placed in position `0.93`, but it is not recalled later on, making useless its definition. The snippet:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\coordinate (col-aa) at ($(col)+(-2,-1.8)$);
\node[align=right,left] at (col-aa) {\small{TEC}};
\path[-stealth,red,draw] (col-aa) -| ($(col)+(1,-1.55)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

is a remain from the initial versions of the package and it could be simplified a lot using markers.

Here is a solution:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[beamer,markings]{hf-tikz}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Total Electron Content} 
        \begin{equation*}               
            \Delta \rho_{ion}=\frac{40.3}{f^2}\tikzmarkin<2>[mark at=0.835]{col}(0.2,-0.5)(-0,0.7)\int_S N_e\mathrm{d}S\tikzmarkend{col}         
        \end{equation*}

\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{
\draw<2->[stealth-,red,draw,use marker id] (0,0)--++(0,-1)--++(-3,0)
node[left,black]{TEC};
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The key `use marker id` allows to start a new path in which the coordinates `(0,0)` identify the point marked previously.

To come back to the issue, here just having the overlay specifications coherent between the highlighted formula and the annotation is enough. With coherence I mean:

```
overlay specification of formula <= overlay specification of the annotation
```

For example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[beamer,markings]{hf-tikz}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Total Electron Content} 
        \begin{equation*}               
            \Delta \rho_{ion}=\frac{40.3}{f^2}\tikzmarkin<2->[mark at=0.835]{col}(0.2,-0.5)(-0,0.7)\int_S N_e\mathrm{d}S\tikzmarkend{col}         
        \end{equation*}

\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{
\draw<3->[stealth-,red,draw,use marker id] (0,0)--++(0,-1)--++(-3,0)
node[left,black]{TEC};
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]