# (Beamer) Highlight node/edge labels using onslide/only

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, labels, highlighting

So in my Beamer slides, I'm using [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6155) to highlight various parts of a tikz figure on different slides.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,automata}

\tikzset{onslide/.code args={<#1>#2}{%
  \only<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}
}}
\tikzstyle{highlight}=[red,ultra thick]

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[->]
      \node[state, onslide={<1>{highlight}}, initial by arrow, initial text={}, initial where=above, label={above left:\(\varnothing\)}] (1) {\(s_1\)};
      \node[state, onslide=<1>{highlight}, label={above left:\(\{a\}\)}] (2) [right= of 1] {\(s_2\)};

      \draw[onslide={<2>{highlight}}] (1) edge node [above] {0.3} (2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Note:** I'm using the tikz libraries `positioning` and `automata`.

It works fine for highlighting the nodes and the edge.
However, on the next slides I want to be able to highlight:

- The labels of the states
- The labels of the edges (and optimally not highlight them on the second slide)
- (optionally) the initial by arrow of `s_1`

I tried inserting `onslide=...` into `label={...}` for the states, but that gives the following error:

```
! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `onslide' (in 'onslide').
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I've added the rest of the example needed for it to be compilable.

Answer (score 2):

I am not entirely sure which elements you want highlight, but if you just want to change the font colour of `S_1` etc, use `\textcolor<overlay>{color}{text}`. So for example `\textcolor<2>{green}{\(\varnothing\)}` will change the colour to green on the second slide.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,automata}

\tikzset{onslide/.code args={<#1>#2}{%
  \only<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}
}}
\tikzset{highlight/.style={red,ultra thick}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[->]
      \node[state, onslide={<1>{highlight}}, initial by arrow, initial text={}, initial where=above, label={above left:\textcolor<2>{green}{\(\varnothing\)}}] (1) {\(s_1\)};
      \node[state, onslide=<1>{highlight}, label={above left:\(\{a\}\)}] (2) [right= of 1] {\(s_2\)};

      \draw[onslide={<2>{highlight}}] (1) edge node [above] {0.3} (2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]