# How to modify Forest nodes in Beamer overlays?

Tags: beamer, overlays, forest

I would like to change a property, say the color, of a `forest` node between overlays in `beamer`. It is proposed [elsewhere](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6135/how-to-make-beamer-overlays-with-tikz-node) to use PGF's keys for this in the general case. <strike>However, this approach doesn't seem to be compatible with `forest`, at least this is what I experience</strike>. The following MWE does <strike>**not**</strike> compile:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{forest}

\tikzset{onslide/.code args={<#1>#2}{%
  \only<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}} 
}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{forest}
[A,name=a [B,name=b,onslide=<2>{red}] [C,name=c] ]
\end{forest}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I could equally well live with a solution along the following lines:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{forest}
[A,name=a [B,name=b] [C,name=c] ]
\only<2>{
    %add parameter red to node b
}
\end{forest}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Any idea how to achieve this?

**Edit:** Thanks to @cfr for making me aware of the stupid bug in my MWE. `\tikzset` was located inside the `forest` environment.

Comment: Did this solve it for you? I didn't have too much time earlier, so I just really tested your code to make sure I could reproduce, copied the stuff I was using and tested it to make sure it worked, and posted the result.  I didn't really try to diagnose the problem. (`\tikzset` can usually come after `\begin{document}` and not only in the preamble, although there are some exceptions to this.)

Comment: @cfr: Yes, I'm really happy with it :) The problem with `\tikset` popped up when putting it inside the `forest` environment (contrary to what I said first). That's probably not so unexpected.

Comment: Oh, right. Yes. That would be likely to cause problems. You can say `/tikz/whatever/.style={...}` etc. after `\begin{forest}` but it is already primed to set *forest* keys at that point, so a `\tikzset` (or a `\forestset`) is not likely to go down well ;).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This code is originally adapted from various answers by other people. It is what I'm currently using for this kind of thing. Hopefully it will help you too.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{forest}
\tikzset{% set up for transitions using tikz with beamer overlays
  invisible/.style={opacity=0,text opacity=0},
  visible on/.style={alt=#1{}{invisible}},
  alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
    \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
  },
  transparent/.style={opacity=0.1,text opacity=0.1},
  opaque on/.style={alt=#1{}{transparent}},
  alerted/.style={color=alerted text.fg},
  alert on/.style={alt=#1{alerted}{}},
}
\forestset{%
  visible on/.style={%
    for tree={%
      /tikz/visible on={#1},
      edge={/tikz/visible on={#1}}}},
  opaque on/.style={%
    for tree={%
      /tikz/opaque on={#1},
      edge={/tikz/opaque on={#1}}}},
  alerted on/.style={%
    for tree={%
      /tikz/alerted on={#1},
      edge={/tikz/alerted on={#1}}}},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{forest}
  [A,name=a [B,name=b,alt=<2>{red}{}] [C,name=c] ]
\end{forest}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: trees]

Obviously you don't need all of the styles I show, but I included them for completeness as you can easily delete them if they are unwanted.

Comment: What is `alerttextdefaultfg`? And `alerted on` does not seem to work.

Comment: @StefanMüller Sorry. Should be `alerted text.fg`. Corrected above.