# How can I use beamer's \only in forest with scope on subtrees?

Tags: beamer, overlays, forest

I'd like to use beamer's `\only` **inside** forest trees. Imagine an MWE like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}

\frame{\frametitle{test}

\only<1>{
\Forest{
  [,phantom
    [S [NP [N [I]]]]
    [S [V [wrote]]]]
}}

\only<2>{
\Forest{
  [S
    [NP [N [I]]]
    [V [wrote]]]
}}

}
\end{document}
```

Which results in two overlays:

[image]

Instead I'd like to embed `\only` inside a single `\Forest` along the following lines to do the same:

```
\Forest{
  [,phantom
    [S,only=<1> [NP [N [I]]]]
    [S,only=<1> [V [wrote]]]
    [S,only=<2>
      [NP [N [I]]]
      [V [wrote]]]]
}
```

Is it possible?

I've seen similar proposals [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112471/61499) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/253384/61499), but they don't seem to match what I'm after.

Comment: So you want essentially to wipe the first tree and draw the second in its place? It seems odd to code that as a single tree, rather than two.

Comment: @cfr Yes, that's what I want indeed ;-) I know it might look odd to draw several trees under a `phantom` node, but I find this very practical, because they'll end up inside one `tikzpicture`. So I can easily draw derivations (i.e. shift subtrees and add edges between them).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure this is a sensible way to do this: is it one tree or two? If you are replacing one tree with another, I'd use two trees; if not, I'd try to keep common parts of the one tree common.

Be that as it may, it is quite straightforward to implement a style with the syntax you want. So, as a hypothetical exercise whose application in the real world I do not recommend, here's one way to do it.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{%
  only/.code args={<#1>}{%
    \alt<#1>{}{\pgfkeysalso{before typesetting nodes={remove}}}
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Another test}
  \Forest{
    [,phantom
      [S,only=<1> [NP [N [I]]]]
      [S,only=<1> [V [wrote]]]
      [S,only=<2>
        [NP [N [I]]]
        [V [wrote]]]]
  }
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: only a tree or only two trees?]

## EDIT

Here's an alternative which I think allows you to specify the tree in a more perspicuous way.

```
\begin{frame}<1-2>{Yet Another test}
  \Forest{
    [S, adopt grandchildren=<2>
      [S [NP [N [I]]]]
      [S [V [wrote]]]
      ]
  }
\end{frame}
```

`adopt grandchildren`, as specified here, adopts all grandchildren, does away with all children (at dead of night) and switches to `phantom` prior to adoption.

[image: adoption ... and murder on slide 2]

Whether this is exactly what you want is dubious, but an approach which allows the code to reflect the tree's structure is, I think, preferable, even if it takes a bit more thought to design precisely the right tool(s) for your work-flow.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{%
  alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
    \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
  },
  define long step={grandchildren}{style}{branch={children,children}},
  adopt grandchildren/.style args={<#1>}{
    alt=<#1>{
      before typesetting nodes={
        tempkeylista=,
        for grandchildren={tempkeylista+/.option=name},
        split register={tempkeylista}{,}{append},
        for children=remove,
      },
    }{phantom}
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}<1-2>{Yet Another test}
  \Forest{
    [S, adopt grandchildren=<2>
      [S [NP [N [I]]]]
      [S [V [wrote]]]
      ]
  }
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```