# Beamer: How to use "beamercolor" in a tikz picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, fonts, color

How might it be possible to change the font color of a `tikzpicture` element to the value of a particular `beamercolor`, e.g. `block title`?-- For example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\frame{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0, 5) node (n1) [text=block title] {I should be the same color as block text.};
    \draw (0, 0) node (n2) {I should be plain black text.};
    \path (n1) edge (n2);
\end{tikzpicture}
} 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `font={\usebeamercolor[fg]{block title}}`. The reason for using `font` here is that `\usebeamercolor` as I understand it essentially inserts a `\color{<color name>}`, so you cannot use it as a colour name directly.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\frame{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0, 5) node (n1) [font={\usebeamercolor[fg]{block title}}] {I should be the same color as block text.};
    \draw (0, 0) node (n2) {I should be plain black text.};
    \path (n1) edge (n2);
\end{tikzpicture}
} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Have you got any recommendation on how I can incorporate usage of this macro inside the text label with overlays a la [using PGF keys](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6155/19135), e.g. so that *I should be the same color as block text* is "block text" color only on a given slide?

Comment: @errantlinguist No tricks needed there, did you try? I tested with the code Matthew Leingang posted, and adding for example `onslide=<2>{font=\usebeamercolor[fg]{block title}}` as a node option works as expected.

Comment: actually, that was in fact a lot less painful than I thought it'd be!