# Need help in understanding answer to "how-to-make-beamer-overlays-with-tikz-node"?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, overlays

Can someone explain this code.
[How to make beamer overlays with Tikz node](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6135/how-to-make-beamer-overlays-with-tikz-node).
In particular I need to know

1. Why do we get three copies of a given slide. If I need to make more than two copies, what should be changed?
2. How does `onslide/.code arg={}` and `temporal/.code arg={}` work?

Comment: The `\temporal` and `\alt` macros are from `beamer`, see [p. 81](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf#page=81). The interesting part is `\pgfkeysalso` that does forward its argument to the key-parser of PGFkeys without setting a parent keypath (like `\tikzset` sets `/tikz`). So `\onslide<3->{highlight}` applies the `highlight` key (in this case a style) to slide 3 and all thereafter. (However if there are no specification in that frame for slide after 3 it will be the last one.)

Comment: It will make however many slides are required. Do you have an example where that's not the case?

Comment: I didn't understand the syntax ..... so that why I asked. But now I know how this works

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Would you like to write an answer?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because solved in comments