# How to adjust 'fill' option in this problem

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I have a question related to 
[How to make beamer overlays with Tikz node](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6135/how-to-make-beamer-overlays-with-tikz-node).
What Do I need to do so that the rectangles get filled with a color when they get highlighted. I am looking for a piece of code that will make the rectangles get a lighter shade of the current color but a general answer that would allow to assign any fill color will be appreciated.
Also present solution assigns same color to text inside the highlighted blocks. How can I make text color different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic idea is to define different style and assign them for different overlay specification.

For changing text colours, simply sue `\textcolor<2->{red}{Feature Extraction}`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzset{onslide/.code args={<#1>#2}{%
  \only<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
}}
\tikzset{temporal/.code args={<#1>#2#3#4}{%
  \temporal<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}}{\pgfkeysalso{#4}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
}}

\tikzset{highlight/.style={fill=#1!30!white}}
\tikzset{highlight2/.style={fill=#1!60!white}}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
 \begin{figure}%[h]
%  \begin{centering}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    system/.style={draw,rectangle,rounded corners=3,minimum width=2cm,text width=1.8cm,text centered},
    node distance=2cm
  ]
    \node [system,onslide=<1>{highlight=blue},onslide=<2->{highlight2=blue},anchor=center] (fe) {Feature Extraction};

    \node [system,onslide=<2>{highlight=red},onslide=<3->{highlight2=red},right=of fe.center] (he) {\textcolor<2->{red}{Feature Extraction}};

  \end{tikzpicture}
%  \end{centering}
  \end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In original question, the boxes can get three colors i-e red,green,blue. So when a particular box gets green, I want to fill it will lighter shade of green. When it gets red, fill also changes to red. and so on

Comment: @NAASI See the edit