# Avoiding double slide in beamer

Tags: beamer, tikz-styles

Here is the code of my presentation:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{
    microtype,
    xcolor,
    graphicx,
    mathtools,
        bbm
}

% LANGUAGE CONFIGURATION
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}

\author{Όνομα}
\title{Τίτλος}

\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]

\everymath{\displaystyle}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Βασικές Υποθέσεις}

\tikzstyle{na} = [baseline=-.5ex]

\begin{itemize}
    \item \{Ένας γεωργός, ένα εκτάριο γης\}$\rightarrow$ παραγωγή \(q\) μονάδες προϊόντος,

    \item 2 διαφορετικά συστήματα παραγωγής:\\
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Παραγωγικότητα
            \tikz[na] \node[coordinate] (n1) {};

    \begin{equation*}   
\tikz[baseline]{
    \node[fill=blue!20,anchor=base] (t1)    
    {$\begin{cases}
    q_c(x) \geq q_o(x)\\
    q_j'>0 \quad \text{και}\quad  q_j''\leq 0
    \end{cases}$};
}
\tikz[baseline]{
\node[fill=red!20,anchor=base] (t2)
    {$\begin{cases}
    w_c \\
    kw_o^i+\left( 1-k\right)w_o^e 
    \end{cases}$};
}
    \end{equation*}

    \item Μοναδιαίο Κόστος Παραγωγής
    \tikz[na] \node[coordinate] (n2) {};
\end{itemize}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\path[->]<1-> (n1) edge [bend left] (t1); 
\path[->]<2-> (n2) edge [bend right] (t2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{itemize}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, the compilation produces two (almost) identical slides. However, I want to have the second one. Which options should I pass to `tikz` in order to do that?

Comment: `\begin{frame}<2>` or  `\documentclass[handout]{beamer}`.

Comment: that worked perfectly!!! (although i thought that it had something to do with `tikz`)

Comment: It is because `\path[->]<2->`; why is it there at the first place? (I mean, did you intentionally put `<2->` there?)

Comment: ok, i see... no i just copied the code

Answer (score 2):

In `tikz.code.tex` line 1975, the following is defined

> ```
> \long\def\tikz@eargnormalsemicolon<#1>#2;{
>     \alt<#1>{\tikz@@command@path#2;}{\tikz@path@do@at@end}
> }
> ```

This makes Ti*k*Z compatible with [beamer](/questions/tagged/beamer). Roughly speaking, commands like

```
\draw<1-3>(0,0)--(2,2);
```

will be translated to

```
\only<1-3>{\draw(0,0)--(2,2);}
```

---

It is worth notice that there are other approach combining Ti*k*Z and beamer. For example [How to make beamer overlays with Tikz node](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6135/how-to-make-beamer-overlays-with-tikz-node).