# change tikz node color from frame to frame

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, tikz-trees

I am trying to change a node color of `Tikz` node with `only` option as:

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor=dvipsnames,xcolor=table]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=12em, level distance=3em,
        every node/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners,
          draw, align=center, font=\footnotesize,
    top color=Red, bottom color=Red, color=white}]]
    \node {Foo}
    child {node{Bar1}}
    \only<1>{child {node{Bar2}}
    \only<2>{child[top color=Blue] {node{Bar2}}
      child {node{bar21}}
    child {node{bar22}}};
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This works fine when no `only` thing is involved, but with `only`, its giving error:

```
Runaway argument?
\centering \begin {tikzpicture}[sibling distance=12em, level distance\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \frame.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> mwe.tex
```

What I am doing wrong here? Please help.

Comment: There is a Ti*k*Z library for beamer overlay specifications. I just forget the name every time...

Comment: @Skillmon `\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}` :)

Comment: https://ctan.org/pkg/aobs-tikz

Comment: @samcarter thank you. Why must it have such a horrible name. I always think: It has `beamer` and `overlay` in its name. Must be `tikz-beamer-overlay`. No, wrong. Or perhaps...

Comment: @Skillmon Me too! I can only remember that the letters `b`, `s`, `o` and `a` are in the package name. I then usually use texdoc and try as many combinations of these until a pdf opens :)

Comment: @BaRud Could you please add an example code that shows how the second overlay should look like? (without the only) I tried to remove the `\only` from your code but I don't get any blue colour in the nodes.

Comment: @BaRud While you wait for an answer to this question, can you go back to your previous ones and look if the answers solve your problems and accept them, if they do?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, the accepted answer of question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6135/how-to-make-beamer-overlays-with-tikz-node solves my problem.

Comment: @samcarter: you just asked for a mwe in a comment, not an answer. I agree mwe is necessary, but for that case, its very complicated to make one. so I leave that as of now.