# Is there an addon for thunderbird to render LaTeX equations on display?

Tags: equations, tools

I mean, if an email contains something like `$\mathcal L = -\frac14 F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}$`, is there an addon to have this rendered into something nicer to read?

Or one to have equations rendered to png images when sending an email?

Comment: slightly related: [Compiling documents online](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3/430)

Comment: As I've mentioned in several other questions, compiling any LaTeX code that someone sends you is potentially a [very bad idea](http://www.texdev.net/2010/04/25/tex-and-security/).

Comment: @TH.: that's true, though one could treat it the same way thunderbird treats remote content - only shown for whitelisted users by default. Also, I only thought of rendering parts of an email containing an `$...$` equation

Comment: Restricting to equations doesn't change the threat.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A quick search on `addons.mozilla.org` revealed two:  [`Equations`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/6247/) that does the conversion on some remote server and [`LaTeX It!`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/48583/) which does it at the recipients PC. In both cases TeX code is transmitted as message body.

Comment: +1, although LaTeX It! doesn't seem to work (thudnerbird 3.0.4 de). Should there also be some "replace equations" button at message composition?

Comment: LaTeX It! is the better one since it uses your local TeX engine.

Comment: ... ok, I had to manually add the LaTeX it to the composing window

Answer (score 1):

how about [Tex the world](http://thewe.net/tex/) ? I am not quite sure it is up to date. And it also be more useful in firefox.

Comment: Looks nice, but does it actually also work with thunderbird? Did you test it?

Comment: no, I did not try.