# Placing temporary files outside of dropbox for compilation: issues with openout_any and nomenclature

Tags: document-configuration, environment-variables

So I store my TeX source files in dropbox for backup and synchronization. Of course, it's annoying when you compile to have dropbox upload and download the changes to the temporary files, so you want to put these somewhere else. Since I use Mac OS X and Linux, I chose `/var/tmp/texBuild` as my output directory for these files. My Makefile includes simply:

```
TMPDIR = /var/tmp/texBuild
FC = pdflatex -output-directory $(TMPDIR)
```

When creating a nomenclature, it complained that it was not authorized to write to that directory. A quick search gave me an answer: edit the `texmf.cnf` to change the variable `openout_any` from `p` to `a`. However I then found this question: [Open a file whose name start with a dot and other strangely named files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13271/open-a-file-whose-name-start-with-a-dot-and-other-strangely-named-files) where it is suggested to not do that system wide. Where can I set this environment variable? In my Makefile? Should I rather pick another output directory than `/var/tmp`? I realize I could have just made a comment to that other question but hopefully my question is sufficiently different to warrant its own question.

Comment: This is a possible duplicate. See [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24753/9043) for which texmf.cnf to alter.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. I didn't even consider that there was multiple texmf I could edit. I just edited the one in `/usr/local/texlive/2010` and it worked. Was that the correct choice? Could I instead set the `openout_any` variable for a given document?

Comment: If you edited the wrong one, then it will work, but there is some chance that a later update to LaTeX will overwrite the file. If you use the correct one, it will not be overwritten. At least, this is my understanding. I'm not sure about setting the output for a particular document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not necessary to alter a `texmf.cnf` file and it's not recommendable either.

A call such as

```
openout_any=a pdflatex file
```

(assuming Bash or similar shell) will override the setting of the variable for the current job. I believe that this can be easily implemented in a `Makefile`.

Altering a `texmf.cnf` file exposes you to security issues. Also this way of doing is not safe, but it's more controllable, as only the current process (and its children, if any) will "see" that setting of the environment variable.

Comment: OK so I added `export openout_any=a pdflatex file` to my Makefile and it solves that problem. I have another problem with how bibtex handles `\@input` but this might require another question.

Comment: Looks like it is related with the `openout_any` too: see the discussion here https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/17978
Can I just add something like `openout_any=a bibtex file`?

Comment: Argh that still doesn't work, even if I put back openout_any=a in the texmf file or if I set TEXMFOUTPUT to my temp directory: The top-level auxiliary file: 

    /var/tmp/texBuild/Masquelet_AIAA2012_LOXPSU.aux
    I couldn't open auxiliary file introduction.aux
    ---line 18 of file     /var/tmp/texBuild/Masquelet_AIAA2012_LOXPSU.aux
     : \@input{introduction.aux
     :                         }