# Can I use PDFLaTeX to produce PDF from user input on a website?

Tags: pdftex, online

What I want to do is take textbox input on a website, use java or javascript to convert it to LaTeX code then output a formatted PDF document to the user.  I am wondering if this is possible and where I can find the information on setting up an interface with PDFLaTeX from my website.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: See in particular: [How can I safely compile other people's LaTeX documents](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10418/2693).

Answer (score 5):

Yes it's possible. You may find any info on pdflatex with `man pdflatex`.
Please read the `shell-escape` section carefully.
Furthermore you may consider to install a TeX Distribution like http://www.tug.org/texlive/.