# Is there any reason to used pdflatex instead of lualatex?

Tags: pdftex, luatex

As I understand it pdflatex has been discontinued,
and the replacement is LuaLaTeX.

But pdflatex is still included in most (all?) distributions,
along with LuaLaTeX.

LuaLaTeX supports lots of new features like otf fonts.

Will I ever need to use pdflatex?
Is it faster?

Comment: Type `texdoc luatex` in your terminal and the first page shows you `beta 0.76.0`. So LuaTeX is far away from stable.

Comment: @lockstep that question focuses heavily on languages. It is also from 2010, so it may be out of date. (Now there is a question for meta, (That has probably been answered -- http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1878/what-shall-we-do-with-future-out-of-date-answers))

Comment: I prefer `pdflatex` for security reasons (see [Is luatex as secure as pdftex?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100932/14500)).

Comment: pdflatex has definitely *not* been discontinued.  if you are preparing a manuscript for publication in a journal, or a formal book series, please check the publisher's requirements.  at least *some* publishers cannot yet handle lualatex in a production setting as it's still too "fluid".

Comment: Jubobs, huh? I don't understand