# LuaLaTex: Where do we stand as of 2014?

Tags: luatex

I've been impatiently waiting to switch from `pdfLaTeX` to `LuaLaTeX`, specially because it has been stated that the latter is the successor of `pdfLaTeX` (as described by Xavier in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/126216/27833).

My question is... what is the current situation, given that they *key* questions are more than 6+ months old.

**key questions**

[Which "TeX" should one use?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22823/which-tex-should-one-use/22825#22825)

[Why choose LuaLaTeX over XeLaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126206/why-choose-lualatex-over-xelatex)

[Using LuaTeX as a replacement for pdfTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32295/using-luatex-as-a-replacement-for-pdftex)

[Drawbacks of XeTeX/LuaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3094/drawbacks-of-xetex-luatex/3106#3106)

[Would you consider Luatex to be ready for a production environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131633/would-you-consider-luatex-to-be-ready-for-a-production-environment)

Is it safe to turn `lua` now?  Is still `XeTeX` better supported and better documented?  Should we keep `pdflatex` for the moment?

I know the immediate answer is "depends on what you want to do", so please think of the regular user who writes reports, a couple of articles and dissertations.  Nothing too fancy, just a normal guy who uses *LaTeX instead of Word*

Do you see any immediate problems by switching to `LuaLaTeX` as of today?  Most important: Any limitations?  Any major advantages?  What are the most biggest inconvenient of switching?

What am I missing if I keep using `pdfLaTeX`?  What would happen if I insist using it?  Is a person who keeps using `pdfLateX` getting left behind?

Comment: Please be a bit more specific about your "nothing too fancy" requirements. E.g., do you have need for OpenType fonts? There are by now some apps that *require* Lua(La)TeX, i.e., they won't run under pdf(La)TeX or Xe(La)TeX. If you want to use one or more of them, I guess you need to compile your tex file under Lua(La)TeX.

Comment: @Mico, I'm sorry, it was Xavier.  I'm correcting it.  Nevertheless, any comments? :)

Comment: In general, I think LuaTeX is very 'safe'.  I have been using it most of the time (via `lualatex`) for about two years; and keep in mind that it is the default engine for ConTeXt, which certainly implies a fair degree of 'safety' regarding its use/usability.  If you operate mainly on the LaTeX surface of things (if I can put it that way) you are unlikely to notice many/most/all changes that are occurring on the LuaTeX level as it advances to version 1.0.  But I can't say this with any particular authority...

Comment: @jon Did you read http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100932 ?

Comment: @PaulGaborit -- Yes, I remember the question (and seem to have it favourited).  However, I do not think that is the kind of 'safe' the OP meant; it certainly was what I meant to imply by the term, which was only that there is a high probability that a document compiled using LuaTeX today via `lualatex` will still be compilable in the future.

Comment: A very nice improvement in LuaTeX's usability, from the perspective of people who run MacOSX and MacTeX, will occur when LuaTeX (current TeXLive/MacTeX2013: version 0.76.0) will be move to version 0.78 (currently in beta). This update is set to occur with the introduction of TeXLive/MacTeX 2014, i.e., in a few short months from now. Specifically, the ability to use external Lua libraries when compiling the tex document on a MacOS X system is reported to be much more stable under LuaTeX 0.78 than it is under version 0.76.

Comment: Since the original post seems unclear, I have added some subsequent questions.

Comment: I switched to LuaLaTeX but I switched back after a while when I ran into trouble with unicode math.