# LuaTex doesn't open installed packages with openin_any=p options

Tags: luatex, security

I plan to launch online LuaTeX compile service.

I installed LuaTeX using TexLive 2015 in CentOS 7.
For security concerns, I want to restrict opening files.
Therefore, I set `openin_any=p`.
But, it also restricts opening template files installed in `texmf-dist`.
Other compilers can read template files.

I tried to compile this file:

```
\documentclass{ltjsarticle}
\usepackage{graphicx}



\title{title}


\author{auth}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{section}

This is sample.

\end{document}
```

I compiled this file by `lualatex sample.tex` and got a message as follow:

```
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.80.0 (TeX Live 2015) (rev 5238) 
 restricted \write18 enabled.
(./sample.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/02/01>
Babel <3.9o> and hyphenation patterns for 1 language(s) loaded.

lualatex: Not reading from /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/ltjsarticle.cls (openin_any = p).

! LaTeX Error: File `ltjsarticle.cls' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: cls)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: I am really on the fence about whether this is really a LuaTeX question or a CentOS 7 concern.  On the other hand I know that some questions don't fit squarely into one or the other.  From the question, and I am sure this is my ignorance speaking, I don't know what code you are trying to tweak.  Are you modifying system files, .tex files, script files?

Comment: I modified `texmf.cnf` and set `openin_any = p`.

Comment: Being paranoiac has consequences ;-) Did you read [Is luatex as secure as pdftex?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100932/is-luatex-as-secure-as-pdftex)

Comment: That's a difference between LuaTeX and the other engines that should be fixed, in my opinion. The “paranoid” setting is meant for excluding all directories except those specifically allowed and, most certainly, `TEXMFMAIN` is to be allowed. Otherwise the engine is completely useless.

Comment: You could make a bug report at the luatex mailing list (http://tug.org/mailman/listinfo/luatex) or the bug tracker http://tracker.luatex.org/

Comment: Of course, this file can be compiled when I set `openin_any = r`.
I reported this problem to the bug tracker.
http://tracker.luatex.org/view.php?id=963

Answer (score 1):

About  TeX as online service:
[http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~hovav/dist/texhack.pdf

About Lua: formats can redefine lua as they want, so

```
local myopen = function(...) print("ERROR: open is not permitted") return false end
local _std = {}
_std.oldopen = io.open
io.open = myopen 
for k,v in pairs(_std) do print(k,v) end
assert(io.open("foo"), 'Error on io.open' )
```

io.open is safe (until _std is hidden)

If one doesn't care about io.open:

```
local myopen = function(...) print("ERROR: open is not permitted") return false end
io.open = myopen 
assert(io.open("foo"), 'Error on io.open' )
```

Comment: Ciao Luigi! I'm not sure this answers the question. If `open_any=p` is set in `texmf.cnf`, then LuaTeX does not read in `TEXMFMAIN`, `TEXMFLOCAL` and `TEXMFHOME`, which is something the other TeX engines do, instead.

Comment: Luatex has a callbacks system and some functions that can exclude kpse: it depends to the format to enable or not (and how)  these callbacks (this is something that should be considered for an online service). In this case there are not callbacks, and kpse is called.  The function kpathsea_name_ok seems to look only $TEXMFOUTPUT in the paranoid mode, so when I set $TEXMFOUTPUT the example works as expected. 
I don't see $TEXMFOUTPUT in my cnf files, so it looks as a distro issue, and not a luatex problem, but I have mailed to kb asking som details.

Comment: Sorry, but I consider this to be a bug in LuaTeX, unless you tell how to reenable looking in the admissible trees when the option is `open_any=p`, like all other TeX engines. Reading only in TEXMFOUTPUT doesn't make much sense, if you can't access `article.cls` to begin with.