# Why is `openin_any = p` restricting access to packages in TEXMFDIST?

Tags: texlive, security, texlive-2020

I'm using `openin_any = p` (set in a custom `TEXMFCNF`) as an additional line of defense in an application that runs on (partially) user-provided LaTeX code. This used to work fine, but after updating to the latest texlive 2020, building pretty much any document now fails:

```
/opt/texlive/bin/x86_64-linux/xelatex: Not reading from /opt/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse-generic.tex (openin_any = p).
! LaTeX3 Error: File 'xparse-generic.tex' not found.
```

From what I understood, even with `openin_any = p` files in `TEXMFDIST` are supposed to be fine. Is this a bug, or is this an intentional change. In any case, I'm looking for a solution that allows access to anything in `TEXMFDIST` in addition to the directory containing my tex file.

Comment: are you referencing the file by an absolute path or `\input{xparse-generic}` and it being found on the path?

Comment: I'm not accessing it directly at all. The tex file is just using various packages with `\usepackage{...}`

Comment: I guess this is something due to the implementation of `\file_input:n`.

Comment: OK I can reproduce here now

Comment: I tried to trim down the tex file to a minimal example, and `\usepackage{fontspec}` seems to be the main culprit.

Comment: @ThiefMaster no it is a binary level feature a minimal example is `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{xparse}\begin{document}\end{document}` which gives the error you show in pdftex and xetex, in luatex  nothing loads at all, article.cls is blocked.

Comment: for luatex see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/292363/luatex-doesnt-open-installed-packages-with-openin-any-p-options

Comment: yeah, I found that luatex question as well - but it's quite old and not the distribution i'm using

Comment: yes but luatex hasn't changed and I see the same in texlive 2020

Answer (score 2):

This was indeed a bug in texlive; after asking on the mailing list they [fixed it](https://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2020-September/046131.html).

Details (also from the [mailing list](https://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2020-September/046137.html)) on why exactly this happened:

> With `openin_any=p` you can load most LaTeX packages normally.  The
> issue specific to xparse(-generic.tex) is that it uses a
> `\pdffilesize`-based (expandable) test to check whether a file exists,
> and as I said in my previous mail, \pdffilesize fails with
> `openin_any=p`:
>
> ```
> export openin_any=p && pdftex '\pdffilesize{sample2e.tex}\bye'
> ```
>
> and that's what Akira-san's patch addresses.
>
> This "old behaviour" you mention is that until a few months ago xparse
> was all loaded in one go in xparse.sty as most packages are (and work
> as they always did), but now it is split into the "loader" (and
> legacy---do not use---interfaces) and the bulk of the code in
> `xparse-generic.tex`. Since the latter uses `\pdffilesize`, it fails with
> `openin_any=p`.