# Use minted without unrestricted shell escape

Tags: minted, shell-escape

The `minted` package requires that I enable unrestricted shell escapes (`-shell-escape`).  This is a bit dangerous: it means that malicious latex files can run arbitrary commands and overwrite arbitrary files on the filesystem.

Is there a way to use `minted` without enabling unrestricted shell escapes?  I know that it needs to call the Pygmentize program, and it calls `ifplatform` which runs the `uname` shell command.  I noticed that there is a "restricted shell escape" feature; is there a way to use `minted` with restricted shell escapes.  Or is there some other way to reduce the risk?

Comment: 'Restricted' shell escape runs commands _which have been checked_, so you can't (or shouldn't) just add things to it. ('The whole of Python' is not really something one can regard as secure if you are being careful.) You can always run Pygmentize by hand. Not sure that's an answer ...

Comment: Is the following minted issue relevant? https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/166

Comment: Somewhat more general question, [online - How can I safely compile other people's LaTeX documents? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10418/how-can-i-safely-compile-other-peoples-latex-documents?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 10):

Recent minted release have a `finalizecache` option that saves the cache in a less transient form, then you can change the document to use the `frozencache` option and from then on `--shell-escape` is not needed and it just uses the ready made files in the cache.

This means you still need shell-escape to create the highlighting but you can give the document to someone in a form that can be run with no access to the shell at all.