# How to divide a non-block C comment in two lines with listings-package

Tags: listings

I'm searching a way to correctly include one piece of C code into Latex document. However, it contains some unusual, but valid structures, including a two-line-comment. Minted handles it right, but its's output has some other  problems. The main problem is that "spanned into two lines" does not appear as a comment line. Here is MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\lstset{language=C,
commentstyle=\color{NavyBlue}}
\begin{lstlisting}
int main(void) {
    //one line comment\
    spanned into two lines
    return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What's the problem with the output? Could you explain a bit?

Comment: The problem: "spanned into two lines" does not appear as a comment line.

Comment: Ah, I see. Sorry, I can't help you, I hope someone else will.

Comment: if pygments is mis-parsing the comment syntax it is best to raise a bug report there: minted just styles what pygments reports.  https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/pygments-main/issues/

Comment: @DavidCarlisle But the OP is using `listings`...

Answer (score 1):

If you can switch to `minted`, the two-line comment is correctly parsed (David, in his comment, thought you were using it).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
    \begin{minted}{c}
    int main(void) {
    //one line comment\
    spanned into two lines
    return 0;
    }
    \end{minted}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To know the differences between `listings` and `minted` see here: [minted vs. listings: pros and cons](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/389191/minted-vs-listings-pros-and-cons).

Answer (score 1):

Because there were no easy solution, I cheated a little bit. I prefixed those problematic comment lines with '@' and added to `\lstset`

```
moredelim=[il][\color{NavyBlue}]{\@}
```

And this did the trick.