# Is there a secure way to use --shell-escape with untrusted content?

Tags: texlive, shell-escape, security

I'm planning to create a service that would allow users to render LaTeX documents online with TeX Live running on the server, and I would like to enable certain features (such as gnuplot) that require `--shell-escape`.

My question is: **Is there a way to enable shell escape in a way that would be secure enough for this purpose?**

And also: **Are there any other security issues that I should consider when compiling untrusted LaTeX code on a server?**

I see that `texmf.conf` has the following list:

```
shell_escape_commands = \
bibtex,bibtex8,\
extractbb,\
gregorio,\
kpsewhich,\
makeindex,\
repstopdf,\
r-mpost,\
texosquery-jre8,\
```

However, I see that `gnuplot` is not in the list, but I can still run `gnuplot` when I put `\pgfkeys{/pgf/plot/gnuplot call={gnuplot}}` in my source, and that seems like a security problem.

Comment: You can (as for example overleaf does, run in a docker container, which you discard afer each run so one job can not harm the next. I do not understand your gnuplot example. Using gnuplot from pgf does require `--shell-escape`

Comment: I am using Docker containers, but somebody could still abuse the system by making repeated calls to run their own code mining bitcoin for example. However, you are making a good point in the sense that setting a time limit for each job and discarding the container afterwards would make abuse more difficult.

Comment: Regarding gnuplot, I thought that `--shell-escape` should only allow command that are listed in the allowed commands list, but gnuplot is not there.

Comment: no, the opposite. They are the commands allowed by default, that do not need `shell-escape`. If you use `--shell-esacape` you have full access to any commad you could run on the commd line.

Comment: Ok. I see. So, if I would like to use gnuplot without the possibility to run any other commands, I could add gnuplot to the list and not use `--shell-escape`, right?

Comment: yes, but the reason gnuplot is not there is that guplot can run system commands so if you add it you have no security. A supplied tex file can write then execute a gnuplot command that can run any command on the system. `repstopdf` and `r-mpost` in that list are carefully tested wrappers around `epstopdf` and metapost that prevent shell access and prevent reading files in parent directories for exactly this reason.

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/726/

Comment: Somewhat special case of  [online - How can I safely compile other people's LaTeX documents? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10418/how-can-i-safely-compile-other-peoples-latex-documents)