# Stable alternative for http://docs.latexlab.org/

Tags: tools, online

I'm looking for an alternative for http://docs.latexlab.org/ which is stable. Is there any?

Comment: To save a click for everyone : "LaTeX Lab is an open source implementation of a web based LaTeX editor for Google Docs."

Comment: @MartylX: please define 'stable' in this context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several Online LaTeX-Editors in my bookmark list:

- [MonkeyTeX](http://monkeytex.bradcater.webfactional.com/), seems very stable and I've also used it before
- [ScribTeX](http://www.scribtex.com/)
- [Verbosus](https://www.verbosus.com/), don't actually know more about it.
- a bit special, since aimed at iDevices, but also online: [TeX Touch](http://www.vancapy.de/textouch/texcloud/) (German site only)

Why you'd want to do that is another question. I'd suggest - if you really want to work on your documents in the cloud - that you look at a text-syncing app like [simplenote](https://simplenoteapp.com/), work on your files on the go and compile them on your machine at home.

Comment: Oh, and BTW: here's a list of online editors in another question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3/compiling-documents-online

Answer (score 1):

If hosting your own Latex service is an option, you can run Google's CLSI code on a server, which is part of the technology behind `docs.latexlab.org`. See the [InstallandConfig page](http://code.google.com/p/common-latex-service-interface/wiki/InstallAndConfig) on the project wiki for instructions on how to do this.

I've been meaning to try this out for a while; if anyone has any experience they'd care to share, I'd be interested.