# Insert LaTex in Web Admin Panel and Visualize LaTex in Android

Tags: android

I don't know whether it is the right place to ask this question or not. I want to have a rich text editor with LaTex support that I want to embed into an admin panel. Moderator can add rich text with text, image and LaTex equation that will be inserted into MySQL database. After inserting I want to get those back to my android application. I can easily do if there is no LaTex. Is there any Idea or solution?

Comment: What is the end result you want to have on Android? The pdf produced by LaTeX or the source TeX code?

Comment: Source TeX Code

Comment: Then for the Android part you can simply use a mobile LaTeX editor app. [This was the first result of a Google search.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=verbosus.verbtex&hl=nl) As for the embeddable rich text editor with LaTeX support you can check out [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41064/embeddable-in-browser-latex-editor-compiler-plugin).

Comment: You didn't get my point bro. User>Insert in Web Interface>Store insertion in MySQL>retrieve data from mysql. Insertion will be text + image + TeX

Comment: Does it work with a simple ascii text file with the ending `.txt`?