# Post-commit service hook for GitHub repository containing LaTeX?

Tags: compiling, repositories, git

This question is related to [Compiling documents online](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3/compiling-documents-online).

I store my LaTeX documents in a git repository on GitHub. Is there a web service which offers a post-commit hook for GitHub which automatically fetches my document and compiles it?

For example, [ReadTheDocs](http://readthedocs.org/) provides compilation for documentation of Python projects stored in GitHub repositories; the documentation is fetched and compiled after each commit to the repository.

Answer (score 6):

http://latex.aslushnikov.com/

Is what you are searching for. Example of compile git repo from some master LaTeX file:

[PDF](http://latex.aslushnikov.com/compile?git=https://github.com/aslushnikov/diplom-latex&target=diplom.tex)

Comment: This is almost what I'm looking for, but there are some issues. 1) It's missing a GitHub post-commit hook for automatic compilation and publishing of compiled documents. 2) (A related issue) The `/compile` URL seems to respond to `GET` requests instead of `POST` requests. 3) There is no way of specifying external LaTeX packages to be automatically downloaded from CTAN. (Necessary because it is bad style to store a copy of all necessary LaTeX packages in my Git repository.)

Comment: Also, if this is a service that you created yourself, you should really disclose this fact: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/15787

Comment: I'm the author of the service. Please, feel free to submit any issues here: https://github.com/aslushnikov/latex-online/issues

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly the answer you want, I guess (and to finish this question):

Have a closer look to [ScribTeX](http://www.scribtex.com/). On the website you can read: "Access to your project's git repository" as mentioned in your cited question [compiling documents online](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3/compiling-documents-online) (see answer of Sharpie).

I do not know other web services offering what you are searching for.

Answer (score 2):

> The ShareLaTeX Cloud Compiler was shut down on the 21st of July 2018. So this answer is not valid any more.

You can use ShareLaTeX on [public repos](https://www.sharelatex.com/github/), but the problem is that you can compile only one file in a repo.

Or you can use a payed version and [sync your ShareLaTeX account with GitHub](https://fr.sharelatex.com/blog/2015/02/10/shareLaTeX-github-sync.html) too.

Comment: The ShareLaTeX GitHub LaTeX continuous integration service seems to be basically what I was looking for. I knew someone would build this service eventually, it just took way longer than I was expecting.

Answer (score 2):

With GitHub Actions you can accomplish this.  There are a few LaTeX actions, the one I found to work most easily is https://github.com/dante-ev/latex-action

You can store the compiled artifact, as I do in my LaTeX git template https://github.com/evanberkowitz/latex-base, so that after every push a new artifact is available for download and after every pull request a PDF with the diffs highlighted is available.

Unfortunately, the latest compiled artifacts' URLs are not stable---there has been [an open issue](https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact/issues/21) for a bit over a year (as of this writing).

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/dbrgn/github-latex-builder

You'd need to self-host it (note security warnings).