# Is there a web-based LaTeX or TeX editor?

Tags: editors, online

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Compiling documents online](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3/compiling-documents-online)

I would like to use a calculator that allows me to write formulas and questions in LaTeX or TeX. Is there anything JS based?

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3/compiling-documents-online contain anything useful?

Comment: @Caramdir I think it's even a duplicate...

Comment: @percusse: I'm not sure what the "calculator" in the question is about.

Comment: @Caramdir I think it's something that you enter a formula and it's typeset with LaTeX after computation such as *what is 34/2?*. And the answer would be something like rendering `$\frac{34}{2}=17$`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9939541/is-there-a-web-based-latex-or-tex-editor?noredirect=1) was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: Check out [Auto-LaTeX Equations for Google Docs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/auto-latex-equations/iaainhiejkciadlhlodaajgbffkebdog?utm_source=https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50134/), it does all the rendering work for you and looks great!

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Scribtex](http://www.scribtex.com/) or [CodeCogs](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php)

Answer (score 3):

[ShareLaTeX](https://www.sharelatex.com/) looks great.

Answer (score 1):

this seems updated: http://www.scribtex.com/

Answer (score 1):

The physics stackexchange partner site uses [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/) and it works beautifully.

Comment: ...same goes for [Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com).