# What LaTeX version should I download and use

Tags: equations

I just want to build math formulas that look nice, no documents, no books.
Thanks

Comment: Which operation system do you use?

Comment: Consider reading [Is there a web-based LaTeX or TeX editor?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50134/5764) You might be interested in an [online LaTeX equation editor](https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php).

Comment: Like most other software the answer will be: "The newest for your OS". I do not know what other type of answer you expect.

Comment: @down-voters Please don't downvote below a score of -1, even if the question in its current form needs some improvement. A score of -1 is enough to show that the question needs work, anything below that is of no use. Also, if you downvote or vote to close, please leave a comment explaining why you did so, but wait at least 24 hours after asking the OP for improvements to the question before voting to close.

Comment: user2817127, don't let the inital downvotes and slighly harsh comments you received here discourage you from asking further questions! @hpekristiansen, obviously OP is not aware of how LaTeX works and thought that "distributions" differ from each other like for Linux...

Comment: @sheß: You are probably correct - I did not even think of that. A follow up from OP explaining, what was meant would have been nice. I still do not see the closure of this question(not by me) as a mistake.

Answer (score 5):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)

You asked,

> [Which] LaTeX version should I download?

and you mentioned that

> I just want to build math formulas that look nice.

Your question appears to imply that you expect there to be various manifestations of LaTeX executables, each with various amounts of power or sophistication. But that's not how LaTeX "works".

The two questions you *should* be asking are: "Once I've downloaded and installed a suitable complete TeX distribution on my computer, which LaTeX *document class* should I employ?" And, "Which LaTeX packages (if any) should I load in the preamble of my LaTeX documents in order to make typesetting various mathematical expressions straightforward?"

Regarding your first question: It sounds like even a "basic" document class such as `article` will do fine. Not knowing what kinds of mathematical typesetting needs you may have, it's not really possible to give an in-depth answer to the second question.

Comment: Thank you Mico. I think I'll start scavenging sample code before asking any more questions.