# iOS Libraries for LaTeX?

Tags: math-mode

I am trying to add support to my app to allow users to type in LaTeX equations and display them within the app. I am not trying to create a LaTeX editing app (this will be one of the features of the app, not the app as a whole), and I'd like to try to find a way to outsource the work of the LaTeX editing and display because I don't see a reason to reinvent the wheel. Are there any libraries for iOS which will either display LaTeX, or that will allow users to easily type in equations? Thanks!

Comment: I neither use nor develop for iOS but would it be possible to use on of the severely online TeX machines? http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3/4918

Comment: itextomml is a C-library for converting LaTeX-like equations into MathML.  You could combine that with a MathML-renderer of some sort.  Would that work?  (I know nothing about iOS development and what is required.)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: One library you can look at for iOS is: https://github.com/kostub/iosMath

Answer (score 4):

If you do not need full LaTeX documents are are just interested in a latex syntax for mathematics, you should probably look at MathJax, a javascript/css library for math display.

There are several discussions of IOS on the mathjax list for example this one gives a step by step guide to one customisation that worked.

[iOS implementation - short list of steps](http://groups.google.com/group/mathjax-users/browse_frm/thread/5392b9353406d1f3?tvc=1&q=ios)