# Are any web base TEX editors with live collaboration available?

Tags: editors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Compiling documents online](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3/compiling-documents-online)

I have grown addicted to the live collaboration features of Google Docs.

Any such solutions available for editing TEX files?

Any web based TEX editors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a LaTeX extension for Google Docs called [LaTeX Lab](http://docs.latexlab.org/). It can be enabled for each Google account. However, the LaTeX compilation is still a bit slow.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this project seems to have been dead for at least a year. Another drawback that I see with this is that using the local latex installation doesn't always work... the thing is buggy.

Answer (score 4):

There is also 
[www.sharelatex.com](http://www.sharelatex.com)

and [brutus.lostpackets.de/ethertex/ethertex.py](http://brutus.lostpackets.de/ethertex/ethertex.py)

and [www.writelatex.com](http://www.writelatex.com)

You can find some information here : [en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Collaborative_Writing_of_LaTeX_Documents](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Collaborative_Writing_of_LaTeX_Documents)

Answer (score 2):

The only site I know is [scribtex.com](https://www.scribtex.com/). It allows live editing and it supports git. Unluckily something like Google Docs is yet to come, but it would be really awesome!

Comment: scribtex is now merging with www.sharelatex.com with the goal of being a Google Docs for LaTeX

Comment: @beck: Would be really nice if they allowed using a local Latex installation (when available) -- that would speed up compile time and would allow one to work offline.

Comment: @William that would be very cool, it is however very hard technically.

Comment: @beck: I don't understand why this should be hard. When you compile, what is really happening is compilation on the server somewhere, and the output is piped to your browser. Now replace that "somewhere" server with the localhost.

Comment: @William, it would involve us building something idiot proof, that can be installed and run on Mac, Windows and Linux, on environment that is hard for us to debug. There are also updates, different versions of texlive, or when we want to change the api we would need all local instances to update as well or support both versions for long periods of time. With us managing the compile servers we know what is going on and can quickly get to the bottom of the problem. Getting something roughly working wouldn't be hard, but in real production terms it is something we don't want to tackle.

Comment: @William I should say though I think in a few months we will be able to get the latest page of the pdf onto your screen using our servers faster than using your local machine.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least a dozen online LaTeX editors. You'll find a list in the B. Complete Documents section at [Online LaTeX Update](http://sixthform.info/steve/wordpress/?p=233)