# Formulae PNG anti-aliasing

Tags: transparency, png, rendering

I would like to render formulae in PNG format for use in various websites. The problem is, every rendering tool I've come across seems to assume a particular background color to perform anti-aliasing, resulting in nasty color fringes when the image is displayed on a different background color. Is there a way to perform the anti-aliasing in the alpha-channel so that the equation will look nice and crisp no matter what color the background it'll be displayed on is?

Or is it not possible?

Comment: One solution is to render in high resolution, and then change white to transparent and then reduce the size, properly mixing black and transparent. I'm sure `ImageMagick`'s `convert` is capable of it.

Comment: There are a number of online equation compilers listed at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1654/4012, in case one of these helps.

Comment: @tohecz Thanks, that sounds like a good suggestion. Right now I've been doing it by rendering to SVG, then to a large transparent PNG, but it's rather long-winded - I will try your method.

Comment: You don't say how you create your pngs. `dvipng` has an option for setting the background colour to transparent: `-bg Transparent`. I expect GhostScript to have a similar option.

Comment: I'm afraid that this does not look on-topic for us. I can see the link to TeX, but really expertise in TeX will not directly help in an answer. Perhaps migration to SuperUser would be appropriate.

Comment: @JosephWright I don't 100% agree. There can be a solution in LaTeX. (Maybe in future versions of `standalone` ?)

Comment: @tohecz As the question stands, there is no mention of how the `.png` files are produced. Also, all `standalone` can do is call some external tool for post-production modification of a DVI or PDF. As such, TeX is not involved in the conversion. A good answer for the question as posed seems to me to be about tools for creating `.png` files.

Comment: @JosephWright I somehow agree. As well, Thomas: you seem to solve your issue since your avatar has changed from white to transparent background. So please, if you don't need any help, we will close this as off-topic (since it even doesn't mention TeX at all), or improve your question to show what help you need from the TeX side of thing.

Comment: I solved it using the ugly way I mentioned above but your method worked tohecz - if you could post it as an answer I could accept it before the question gets closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a possibility to use ImageMagick's `convert`: you first generate a hi-res image, then you change white to transparent, and finally you scale the image down.