# What is the most efficient way to render LaTeX to a viewable format on a server?

Tags: pdftex, pdf, memory, jpeg

I am working on an online web-app that incorporates LaTeX document generation.

Currently, as a beginner to LaTeX (but the most experienced developer in my team), I am trying to determine the most efficient way to generate LaTeX docs into a viewable format. Memory is a concern to us, so here are our methods to begin with.

---

`> latex sample.tex`

Outputs a `dvi` which I can then convert to a `png` or a `pdf`

---

`> pdflatex sample.tex`

Outputs a `pdf` directly

---

Those are the main two methods I have used so far, other methods have either failed or been found to be too complex.

If anything, a `.tex` file directly to a `jpeg` would seem the most efficient, but I would prefer for some expert opinions;]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about)

Comment: Please have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3/compiling-documents-online. I'm not sure to what extend it is possible, but maybe it would be better to reuse existing code instead of recreating everything from scratch.

Comment: Have a look at [dvisvgm](http://dvisvgm.sourceforge.net/). It converts dvi to svg.

Answer (score 1):

TeX and derivatives can only produce output directly in two formats, DVI and PDF. The DVI format can be converted into several others, but there is no direct way to produce for example a JPEG. (Note: there are workflows which hide the detail, but in teh end there is a conversion step somewhere to get say a JPEG or `.png` file)

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain `jpg` or `png` files from latex source with the help of imagemagic. Consider this code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert,png={size=210,density=600}]{standalone}
\tikzset{
  edge down and up again/.style={
    to path={
       |- ([shift={(\tikztotarget.south)}] +0pt,+-2.5mm) -- (\tikztotarget) }}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (10, 10) (root) {root} ;
\node at (10, 7) (lvl1middle) {lvl1middle} ;
\node at (8, 6) (lvl2left) {lvl2left} ;
\node at (13, 5) (lvl2right) {lvl2right} ;
\node at (10, 5) (lvl2middle) {lvl2middle} ;

\path[edge down and up again] (root) edge [line to] (lvl1middle)
                        (lvl1middle) edge           (lvl2left)
                                     edge [line to] (lvl2middle)
                        (lvl2middle) edge           (lvl2right);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Save the above code as `myfile.tex`. Compile it with `pdflatex` with `shell escape` option. You should get a `myfile.png` file. For details consult `standalone` class documentation.

The above can also be achieved by following code that doesn't use `standalone`. Here `demo.tex` is your actual file whose contents are needed as image. This makes use of `shell escape` capabilities. :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{demo.tex}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}
%
%compile pdf first
\immediate\write18{pdflatex demo}
%
% convert to jpg
\makeatletter
\immediate\write18{convert -density 200 -alpha on demo.pdf demo-\@percentchar02d.jpg}
\makeatother
%
\begin{document}
Checkout the folder for image files.
\end{document}
```

You will get two files in the same directory - `demo-00.jpg` and `demo-01.jpg` with each page resulting in a `jpg` file.

Answer (score 0):

This may have been solved by mediawiki, I'm not an expert but you may want to look at [the Texvc addon](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Texvc) -- or rather I think texvc is a a standalone programme that supports the mediawiki math extension.