# I'm having problems with PDF preview

Tags: texworks

I just started using TeXworks, and for some reason, I'm having problems with PDF preview. 
For example, when I type,

```
\documentclass[12 pt, a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}

\section{}



\section{}

\section{}

\section{}


Left Cosets:\\

eH=\{e, (1 2)(3 4), (1 3)(2 4), (1 4)(2 3)\}\\

(1 2) = \{(1 2), (3 4), (1 3 2 4), (1 4 2 3)\}\
```

...and then click play, the pdf viewer has no problems. But when I continue typing..

```
(1 4)=\{(1 4), (1 2 4 3), (1 3 4 2), (2 3)\}\\

(1 2 3)= \{(1 2 3), (1 3 4), (2 4 3), (1 4 2)\}\\

(1 3 2)=\{(1 3 2), (2 3 4), (1 2 4), (1 4 3)\}\
```

...and then click on play again...it doesn't show the second part that I added. Can anybody help me with this? There are no LaTeX problems with I typed either. I know there are spaces between the lines here (but I don't have the spaces in TeXworks).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/19384) I do not think the problems relate to TeXworks since it is only a front end. Could you specify what LaTeX distribution you are using and particularly how you compile your document (pdfLaTeX/LaTeX/other?)

Comment: is it what you are expecting ? https://www.writelatex.com/75540wckwqd

Comment: @PeterJansson What do you mean by "LaTeX distribution"? The one I'm using is "pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX".

Comment: I was thinking of MiKTeX/TeXLive, complete install/or not. Such information could also be useful for someone to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @texenthusiast Thanks a lot...but that doesn't happen in texworks. How did it happen in that link?

Comment: @Artus i checked with texworks on linux, it works as well. Did you go through this link at TUG for "LaTeX distribution?"  http://www.tug.org/levels.html. using terminal window(linux) or command window(windows) try running the `pdflatex -v` to check if you have "LaTeX distribution" installed, if yes run `pdflatex your-filename.tex` from the command window/terminal

Comment: @texenthusiast For the link that you gave (writelatex.com)...I can use that instead of texworks, right? I can write something and print it from there, right?

Comment: @Artus texworks is an TeX editor on your local machine which uses `pdflatex` engine from a ""LaTeX distribution" to generate pdf document, whereas writelatex.com is a online latex compiler where you can see the source and output pdf in the browser(as texlive LaTeX distribution is installed on the webserver).  When you are in hurry or small and quick latex example, you can use writelatex.com. But for heavy stuff(more files and attachments) try local machine when internet is not available. I recommend installing texlive 2012(latex distribution) and texworks as editor.

Comment: @Artus please go through http://www.ctan.org/starter. It will help you to install "LaTeX distribution". I have noticed in your code `\end{document}` is missing. Is this the cause of your error ? Please post the details of error messages( inside the `your-filename.log`) so that someone here can help you.

Comment: @texenthusiast Yes that was the error...anyways, I think I like writelatex more than texworks because it saves everything automatically and numbers the lines. I'm not planning to do anything complicated; I just want to type my exam using latex, so I think writelatex is enough for me. Anyways, thanks again.

Comment: @Artus its your choice always. see more [list of online latex compilers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1654/15717). If your problem is resolved shall i make a simple answer to finish the proceedings ?.

Comment: @texenthusiast Yes sure :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- In your LaTeX code `\end{document}` is missing at the end of
  document.Once you add this works fine on TeXworks or any TeX editor.
- Your problem is not related to TeXworks editor as TeXworks just
  compiles the source code on local machine using `pdflatex` engine to
  generate pdf document.`pdflatex` engine is available from any "LaTeX
  distribution" like TeXlive and MiKTeX.
- for detailed information on [What is "LaTeX distribution" vs Editors
  ?](http://www.tug.org/levels.html)

**Basic Troubleshooting issues**:

- When in trouble compiling LaTeX source code from a TeX editor ?

  **Always double check using terminal/command windows approach to narrow down 
   diagnosis of problems**
- Type `pdflatex -v` at the terminal window(linux) or command
  window(windows) to check if you have an "LaTeX distribution"
  installed and to know its version.
- If `yes` run `pdflatex your-filename.tex` from the command window/terminal 
  else install any [LaTeX distribution](http://www.ctan.org/starter)
- Last important step would be to report the details of error messages inside
  the `your-filename.log` generated during `pdflatex your-filename.tex` 
  compilation
- For a quick debugging and short LaTeX example you can always utilise [Online 
  compilers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1654/15717) to verify your 
  problems.