# texlive.js possible?

Tags: javascript

I just found about [emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki),
[texlive.js](http://manuels.github.com/texlive.js/website/) is it really a converted version of texlive in JavaScript or a server as [Scribtex](http://www.scribtex.com/) and many others?
Is this really possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a legit LaTeX compiler that runs in JavaScript. It does depend on some static files from the server (fonts, packages, etc), but it does not need server-side execution, this means that the data you insert on that page is not transmitted over the wire.

Proof: I watched the HTTP stream using [Webscarab](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_WebScarab_Project) after cleaning browser. There are HTTP requests, but these only ask for dependencies (packages, ...) and do not send any LaTeX source to the server (see below).

[image: Webscarab screenshot]

I also took a brief look at [the source](https://github.com/manuels/texlive.js) and the project description and using emscripten is a nice idea to bring such applications to the browser, it saves a lot rewriting overhead (programmers time!). The PDF that is generated is also generated on the client, not on the server side.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is possible. Emscripten is quite powerful, there are ports of gnuplot, lua and various games. The github repository to the project has more information and the source files at https://github.com/manuels/pdftex.js.

The author says

> It's under development and not ready to use, yet.

So we have to wait a bit how the development progresses.

Comment: Your answer was good, but I had to choose. thank you