# Get TeX to work with jsPdf

Tags: pdf, code, javascript

`jsPdf` is a `Javascript` library that creates `pdf` documents on the fly.

This is very useful to me as I have a familiarity with `Javascript` and I want to be able to do this operation server-side.

However, it doesn't produce my `TeX`. It just puts out `''$2+4x^2 = 0''` in the `Hello World` demo when I modify it.

There must be something I can put in the metadata section/preamble/header/whatever it is to tell the part of the `Javascript` file that I want it to go through whatever package it is to render with `TeX`.

Thank you for any help.

-Eka

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your question might be not soluble by this forum because `jsPdf` probably contains no `TeX` engine -- it might not be able to 'translate' `TeX` code into direct `pdf` output.

Comment: Well, there's a `pdflatex` implementation in `JavaScript`, see: http://manuels.github.io/texlive.js/

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101977/texlive-js-possible