# Integrating equation into Google Docs

Tags: equations, embedding

I'm just wondering whether or not it is possible to have LaTeX equations inside my Google doc? At the moment, I'm including images of the equation which isn't really the desired method I would like to choose. For example:

`Y[n] = X[n] - 0.95 \cdot X[n - 1]  \hspace{.5in} (1)`

Whenever I insert the above into the equation editor, it does not format correctly, or, show up, just shows up as the raw code.

Any ideas or suggestions would be most welcome.

Comment: welcome to tex.sx, see if the solutions here help (if so we can close this as duplicate) http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3/compiling-documents-online

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Hey, thank you for welcoming me! And nope, sadly not.

Comment: The question there is more general but some of the answers cover google docs (and point, as does a google search) to [latex lab](http://docs.latexlab.org/) (about which I know nothing)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yep. I have tried latex lab, and, it does not provide a solution as of such :(! I'll just include images, it should be fine! Thanks though