# Latex easy downloads

Tags: editors

Can anyone help me find a suitable latex software that already includes an editor. I tried downloading MikeTex but it tells me to download an editor which I am not familiar with. I am not a hardcore latex user; I just want to use it while doing some notes and other miscellaneous things. What are the easiest downloads for LaTex?

Comment: Make your pick: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides/

Comment: @T.Verron Lol I see this question has been asked a lot! Sorry about that and thank you for that site!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  I would just recommend downloading TeXLive2012. It comes with `TeXWorks` (and `TeXShop` on Mac).

Comment: @T.Verron Can you recommend me one that doesn't require a full template like style. For example, in math.stackexchange all you have to do is just wrtie in latex and it appears as you wish. Are there any software like that?

Comment: @PeterGrill Thanks Peter! Same question I asked Verron is the software you recommend as easy to use like in math.stackexchange? All you have to do there is just wrtie in latex and it appears as you wish.

Comment: Sorry if that is a dumb question

Comment: I think you will always need a preamble (that's how latex users call this "template style"), but you can quite easily find some basic preambles (in any good latex tutorial) to start with, and then forget it as long as it suits your needs. There are also some software which aren't technically latex editors, but support latex export. In these cases, the exporter takes care of the preamble for you. LyX and emacs org-mode fall into this category for example.

Comment: @T.Verron Thanks! If you want, you can write your comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @Q.matin: In Math.SE you are only entering code snippets, in the editors you need to enter a complete document. A basic one to start with (assuming you are doing some math) is `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{amsmath} \begin{document} ... \end{document}`. Just put your LaTeX code where the `...` is. If you are on a PC use 'TeXWorks` but if you are on a Mac I prefer `TeXShop`.

Comment: @Q.matin (cont'd) There may be better editors out there (refere to the question T. Verron provided a link to), but these are good enough to get started with. These editors don't give you a real time preview, but selecting 'Typeset' will produce a PDF for you.

Comment: Since pointing to the online Latex services (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3/compiling-documents-online) counts as an answer to this question and not the IDE question, I don't think this is a duplicate of the IDE question.  I'm voting to reopen.