# Mathscr fonts from the mathrsfs package not showing up in PDF

Tags: fonts, pdftex, pdf

Long time lurker, first time poster: I am having trouble getting `mathscr` to work properly. In the past, I have always created PDFs by LaTeX->DVI->PDF, and when I do this, the package has always worked properly, in the sense that it renders in the DVI and also in the PDF. I recently started compiling directly to PDF from LaTeX, and this works great EXCEPT for this font.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathrsfs} 
\begin{document}

$\mathscr{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$

\end{document}
```

An example of the output generated by my compiler (PCTeX v. 6.1) can be seen in the following two PDFs:

[LaTeX->PDF](http://www.phys.ksu.edu/personal/werbsen/latex_pdf.pdf),

[LaTeX->DVI->PDF](http://www.phys.ksu.edu/personal/werbsen/latex_dvi_pdf.pdf)

We see that the second link is what we would expect, while the first has something wrong. I assume that there is something wrong with the fonts, in that somehow the information is not being passed correctly to the PDF so that it is interpreted as Latin characters.

I have tried manually reinstalling the font (rsfs10.pfb), and checked my version of Adobe. I also tried copying the Type 1 fonts from MiKTeX over to the PCTeX directory to no avail.

I am not sure what to do at this point... my thesis is due tomorrow and am running out of time. I should also mention that the main reason I am so attached to the `mathscr` fonts is that I use `$\mathscr{E}$` to signify a quantity which is labeled with the same character in many figures scattered throughout my thesis.

Comment: Since you seem to have MiKTeX as well, does it work there? I’ve never heard of PCTeX before, but its pdfTeX seems really outdated, its v. 1.20a, whereas my MiKTeX 2.9 has 1.40.13. Since you’re running out of time, an online compiler from [Compiling documents online](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3) might be an option. This seems to work: https://www.writelatex.com/158244wdxwlg. And you can even upload external files, if needed. Good luck!

Comment: your version of pctex appears to be current.  since this is a commercial product, you should be able to ask for technical support from the company.

Comment: I'll vote for closing as too localized: It works with TeXLive 2012 and PCTeX is a commercially supported product. So either call them or install TL.