# Edit a pdf file in LaTeX?

Tags: pdf, editors

My coworker sent me a paper that we are both working on as a pdf and I need to use LaTeX to continue to work on it. Can I open the pdf in LaTeX and edit it and add to it?

Comment: Welcome to this part of the galaxy!

Comment: You can certaily edit the PDF file using `tikz` and `overlay`, but then you will have a edited PDF file, but if you want to get these changes back into the source .tex file, you will need to edit the source LaTeX file

Comment: You deleted accidently the *.tex source file?

Comment: @PeterGrill I wouldn't say that allowed you to *edit* the PDF. It allows you to *annotate* it. But that is not really the same. It won't let you add a sentence, for example, unless you want to add it into the margins are have space available. Or suppose you need to remove or add `not` in a sentence ....

Comment: If you and your colleague work together on the same paper, you should definitely consider an online tool designed properly for that purpose: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3/compiling-documents-online

Comment: @cfr: Yes, _annotate_ is the correct word.

Comment: To be clear: In LaTeX you edit a plain text file (with the `.tex` extension)  that produce the PDF. If you want changes in the PDF, you *must* edit the text file to produce a *new* PDF.   The PDF is the *final* outcome, LaTeX cannot change it.

Answer (score 13):

No. This is not possible. Your coworker needs to send you the `.tex` file which contains the source for the PDF.

Answer (score 2):

If you only have to add to the pdf file then the pdfpages package could help.  But if you have to change anything on the pages your co-author has written then you're out of luck and your co-author will have to send you the latex file.

Answer (score 1):

there is a source code of xpdfedit, which is actually a mupdf viewer with a workaround to use TeX and comments, directly on the PDF. You can write annotations, like in TeX. [www.gitlab.com/openbsd98324/xpdfedit](http://www.gitlab.com/openbsd98324/xpdfedit)